# How can I return an anonymous type from a method?

Tags: c#, linq, data-structures, parameter-passing

I have a Linq query that I want to call from multiple places:

```
var myData = from a in db.MyTable
             where a.MyValue == "A"
             select new  {
                            a.Key,
                            a.MyValue
                          };
```

How can I create a method, put this code in it, and then call it?

```
public  ???  GetSomeData()
{
   // my Linq query
}
```

Comment: Why don't you return Diction<K,V>?

Comment: this was just a simple example.  I have a lot more values that I'm actually selecting that don't fit into a dictionary

Comment: possible duplicate of [Return anonymous type?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/534690/return-anonymous-type)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

IQueryable and IEnumerable both work. But you want to use a type specific version, IQueryable`<`T`>` or IEnumerable `<`T`>`.

So you'll want to create a type to keep the data.

```
var myData = from a in db.MyTable
             where a.MyValue == "A"
             select new MyType
             {
                 Key = a.Key,
                 Value = a.MyValue
             };
```

Comment: THANK YOU so much for expanding on this solution.  The key was using a specific type.  This works great

Comment: Hey I gave that answer 1 hour befor Darren. Serves me right for not giving a sample:)

Comment: To be clear, what's happening is that select new {...} creates an anonymous type (requiring the use of var keyword). This type has no name and can only be used locally in the method that created it (unless you use reflection). To use it outside, you need to created a named type.

Answer (score 8):

[`IQueryable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.iqueryable.aspx)

So your method declaration would look like

```
public IQueryable GetSomeData()
```

Comment: By doing this you won't have intellisense and can only access the properties of items through reflection.

Comment: Be aware that the query has not running yet.

Comment: Yes I just noticed this..I don't have intellisense.  There must be a better way.

Comment: It depends on your definition of better way. Lazy loading is nice for many circumstances.

Answer (score 3):

A generic method should give you intellisense:

```
public class MyType {Key{get;set;} Value{get;set}}

public IQueryable<T> GetSomeData<T>() where T : MyType, new() 
 { return from a in db.MyTable
          where a.MyValue == "A" 
          select new T {Key=a.Key,Value=a.MyValue};
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to return, you need a type.

Instead of `var`, declare using `IEnumerable<>` and return that variable. Iterating through it actually executes the query.