# Linq to Entities simple group query

Tags: sql, linq, linq-to-entities

How to write (simple) LINQ to Entities query that groups elements by some attribut and count them?

```
SELECT answernumber, count(answerID) FROM answers
WHERE questionID = id
GROUB BY answernumber
ORDERBY answernumber;
```

That should be simple but i don't know how to write it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var query = answers
   .GroupBy(a => a.answernumber, a => a, (k, g) => new {answernumber = k, Count = g.Count()})
   .OrderyBy(i => i.answernumber);
```

Or the other way:

```
var query2 = from a in answers
         group a by a. answernumber into g
         orderby g.Key
         select new { answernumber = g.Key, Count = g.Count() };
```

Comment: how could I return this anonymus type to the method which calls the function with this query?

Comment: Use: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1070526/how-to-return-anonymous-type-from-c-method-that-uses-linq-to-sql, but if you want to screw with your co-workers use: http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2009/01/09/horrible-grotty-hack-returning-an-anonymous-type-instance.aspx

Comment: But with such a simple query, you could just store it in a dictionary