# How to return Anonymous Type while using Linq

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, anonymous-types

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [LINQ to SQL: Return anonymous type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/534690/linq-to-sql-return-anonymous-type)

Do any one know how to return an anonymous type. I am using Linq where i need to return the following code

```
private <What's the return type to be provided here> SampleLinq(Int32 Num)
    {
        var query = (from dept in obj.DeptTable where dept.Id == Num select new { dept.DeptName, dept.DeptId });
        return (query)       

    }
```

Comment: Dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1070526/how-to-return-anonymous-type-from-c-method-that-uses-linq-to-sql-closed

Comment: @Krunal - that one is closed as a duplicate of the one I used.

Comment: @ChrisF - Yup, know that. but let OP see everything.

Answer (score 4):

Sorry to say but you cannot return anonymous type out side the scope of method.

This is the alternate way to get anonmous type

```
// Method that returns anonymous type as object
object ReturnAnonymous()
{
  return new { City="Prague", Name="Tomas" };
}

// Application entry-point
void Main()
{
  // Get instance of anonymous type with 'City' and 'Name' properties
  object o = ReturnAnonymous();

  // This call to 'Cast' method converts first parameter (object) to the
  // same type as the type of second parameter - which is in this case 
  // anonymous type with 'City' and 'Name' properties
  var typed = Cast(o, new { City="", Name="" });
  Console.WriteLine("Name={0}, City={1}", typed.Name, typed.City);
}

// Cast method - thanks to type inference when calling methods it 
// is possible to cast object to type without knowing the type name
T Cast<T>(object obj, T type)
{
  return (T)obj;
}
```

you can use it only for types in one assembly (two anonymous types from two different assemblies will be internally compiled to two different types that can't be converted using this trick).

Answer (score 3):

Return Dynamic type:

```
      public static dynamic  getCustomer() 
{ 
    ..... 
    var x = from c in customers 
            select new {Fname = c.FirstName}; 

    return x; 
} 

static void Main(string[] args) 
{ 
    dynamic x = getCustomer(); 
    Console.WriteLine(Enumerable.First(x).Fname); 
    Console.ReadKey(); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can't do that. that is why it is called anonymous. It doesn't have a name. But you always can cast it to `object`

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can't actually do that, but [here's a hack](http://tomasp.net/blog/cannot-return-anonymous-type-from-method.aspx) on this.

Comment: It would be better to at least add a brief description of the hack in case the link you offer dies.

Answer (score 0):

You can't return an Anonymous Type from a method.

You can create a simple Class to wrap the Anonymous Type, but you still need a Class (or cast to `object`).

Keep in mind, though, that if you cast to `object` there's no way to cast back. You'll need reflection to read any data.

Answer (score 0):

```
private object SampleLinq(Int32 Num)
{
return (from dept in obj.DeptTable where dept.Id == Num select new { dept.DeptName, dept.DeptId });
}
```

Comment: but how to re-cast the object to var to get the properties as object does  not contain public definition for getenumerator?

Comment: Without additional direction such as FirstOrDefault(), the query is going to return an IEnumerable<>. And then you have to use Reflection to figure out how to use it.

Comment: @renjithmaxy - "var" != "<my anonymous type>".  A *var* is still strongly typed at compile time.

Answer (score 0):

The answers you see from the hack is a lot of work just to get an anonymous type through a method boundary.  You shouldn't be doing this.  If you need to pass something back from a method, you should be passing concrete types.

Comment: @Mathew - In general I would agree with you but in cases of databinding the target property (ex. DataContext) is just type object anyway and the binding's are not really bound until runtime. So for example it may be useful to return a IEnumerable that enumerates over instances of an an anonymous type that act like readonly wrappers/ViewModels for a given collection.  So in some cases I think it may make sense to allow returning instances of an anonymous type.

Comment: @jpierson - For sure, I think there are always exceptions to the rule. I am hoping in this instance that it could be one of those times, but in situations where you're trying to access those members in code, it's time to switch from anonymous to statically-typed instances.

Comment: @Mathew - Agreed, like when you are using reflection in code just to get at the values. There are probably a slim set of examples where it might be legitimate but otherwise you are really trying to do dynamic programming in a statically typed language. Now with the dynamic keyword I can see where some C# developers may begin to get a bit eccentric with their use of dynamic style programming but to excess it quickly becomes an unnecessary divergence from the benefits of using a strongly typed language like C#.

Answer (score -1):

It depends what you looking to do with the return vale.

- If your going to bind it in the UI
  you can just rerun
  *IEnumerable* or *IQueryable*.
- If your going to use reflection on the return value just return type object
- If your using c# 4.0 you can return a
  dynamic type
- If your using *EF* or *Linq to SQL* to further join a query comprised of your anonymous type you
  can make a concrete class instead and
  use the concrete placeholder
  technique. For more details on this
  technique I can give some assistance.

As others have mentioned though, you should really question whether returning an anonymous type form a method is the best way to solve the problem at hand. In general there is usually a better more pattern based approach that may require a bit more coding up front but may resulting in a more elegant design. This being said, I do believe there are legitimate cases such as with data binding where returning anonymous type instances can be perfectly acceptable.

**UPDATE**:
Just an interested tidbit I wanted to share in case those reading are not aware. Anonymous types are unique per their property names and types so lets say you have method A and method B in in both you create an anonymous type that has a single string typed property called Name by doing something like be code below.

```
public object A()
{
    return new { Name = "Cid" }
}

public object B()
{
    return new { Name = "Galuf" }
}

public void Test()
{
   System.Diagnostics.Trace.Assert(A().GetType() == B().GetType());
}
```

Now even though this type is defined in two separate places the compiler only creates only creates a single shared type because they both have the same set of properties as defined by the property types and property names. In this respect the properties can be thought of as sort of a signature for the anonymous type. Using this knowledge there are different techniques that can be used for introspection into anonymous type instances that have been cast to object or deferred using the dynamic keyword. There are also nifty ways to work with anonymous types by using generic methods just as Linq does with methods in the static Enumerable and Queryable classes. This way you can do things like create a new instance of any given anonymous type and without using reflection. The trick is though that you have to use an instance of the anonymous type to pass to methods in order to have the type be inferred by the generic method. If anybody is interested in these topics further as they apply to the original posters question, leave a comment and I can try to clarify some of these techniques.

Comment: really! No comments to explain the down votes?

Comment: +1 I never knew those types could be equal! The downvote could be because of your `The trick is though that you have to use an instance of the anonymous type to pass to methods in order to have the type be inferred by the generic method. If anybody is interested in these topics further as they apply to the original posters question, leave a comment and I can try to clarify some of these techniques.` and not writing what it is.