# Return Anonymous Type from a function

Tags: c#, linq, generics, collections

Can I use an anonymous type as a return type in a Function, and then stuff that returned value into an array or collection of some sort whilst also adding an additional field to the new array/collection? excuse my pseudocode...

```
private var GetRowGroups(string columnName)
{
var groupQuery = from table in _dataSetDataTable.AsEnumerable()
                             group table by new { column1 = table[columnName] }
                                 into groupedTable
                                 select new
                                 {
                                     groupName = groupedTable.Key.column1,
                                     rowSpan = groupedTable.Count()
                                 };
    return groupQuery;

}

private void CreateListofRowGroups()
{
    var RowGroupList = new List<????>();
    RowGroupList.Add(GetRowGroups("col1"));
    RowGroupList.Add(GetRowGroups("col2"));
    RowGroupList.Add(GetRowGroups("col3"));

}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Accessing C# Anonymous Type Objects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/713521/accessing-c-sharp-anonymous-type-objects)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Return anonymous type?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/534690/return-anonymous-type)

Comment: Return a tuple, C# 7 feature. You can read more here: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/08/24/whats-new-in-csharp-7-0/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to return Anonymous Type from method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1329672/is-there-a-way-to-return-anonymous-type-from-method)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This is a [very popular question](http://www.google.com/search?gcx=c&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=return%20anonymous%20type%20site:stackoverflow#sclient=psy-ab&hl=en&source=hp&q=return%20anonymous%20type%20site:stackoverflow.com&pbx=1&oq=return%20anonymous%20type%20site:stackoverflow.com&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=3147l3595l0l3599l4l1l0l0l0l0l0l0ll0l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.&fp=8281380e0ebeaaac&biw=1280&bih=858).  In general you cannot return an anonymous type due to the requirement of strong typing.  However there are a couple of workarounds.

1. Create a simple type to represent the return value.  (See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/534690/linq-to-sql-return-anonymous-type) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1070526/how-to-return-anonymous-type-from-c-method-that-uses-linq-to-sql)).  Make it simple by [generating from usage](https://web.archive.org/web/20091027041315/http://diditwith.net/2009/10/24/NamingAnonymousTypesWithGenerateFromUsage.aspx).
2. Create a helper method to [cast to the anonymous type](http://tomasp.net/blog/cannot-return-anonymous-type-from-method.aspx) using a sample instance for casting.

Comment: Please always quote a little snippet from external links. In this case, the first one is broken so your answer is quite useless.

Comment: "generating from usage" link is broken

Comment: @dlchambers: Thanks. I changed the link to use an archive from the wayback machine.

Comment: @mellamokb, people besides OP have this result show up as one of their top google hits so redirecting every future user back to google is entirely unhelpful.  Thank you for the effort in answering, but please inline important information in answers, or just leave a comment if you're merely repointing to other resources.

Answer (score 21):

No you *can't* return an anonymous type from the method. For more info read [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx) MSDN doc. Use `class` or `struct` instead of an `anonymous` type.

You should read blog post - [Horrible grotty hack: returning an anonymous type instance](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2009/01/09/horrible-grotty-hack-returning-an-anonymous-type-instance/)

If you are using framework 4.0 then you can return `List<dynamic>` but be careful to access the properties of anonymous object.

```
private List<dynamic> GetRowGroups(string columnName)
{
var groupQuery = from table in _dataSetDataTable.AsEnumerable()
                             group table by new { column1 = table[columnName] }
                                 into groupedTable
                                 select new
                                 {
                                     groupName = groupedTable.Key.column1,
                                     rowSpan = groupedTable.Count()
                                 };
    return groupQuery.ToList<dynamic>();
}
```

Comment: Now at: https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2009/01/09/horrible-grotty-hack-returning-an-anonymous-type-instance/

Answer (score 4):

No, you can't return an anonymous type directly, but you can return it using an [impromptu interface](http://code.google.com/p/impromptu-interface/).  Something like this:

```
public interface IMyInterface
{
    string GroupName { get;  }
    int RowSpan { get; }
}

private IEnumerable<IMyInterface> GetRowGroups()
{
    var list =
        from item in table
        select new
        {
            GroupName = groupedTable.Key.column1,
            RowSpan = groupedTable.Count()
        }
        .ActLike<IMyInterface>();

    return list;
}
```

Comment: Cute, however I'm not so sure this is any easier than just making the type concrete... (the tooling in IDE's can help)

Answer (score 2):

Just use and ArrayList

```
    public static ArrayList GetMembersItems(string ProjectGuid)
    {
        ArrayList items = new ArrayList(); 

              items.AddRange(yourVariable 
                        .Where(p => p.yourproperty == something)
                        .ToList());
            return items;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `object`, not `var`. You'll have to use reflection to access the properties outside the scope of the anonymous type though.

i.e.

```
private object GetRowGroups(string columnName) 
...
var RowGroupList = new List<object>();
...
```

Comment: This could later be accessed through `dynamic` (C#4) ... however it loses all practical type-safety.

Answer (score 0):

From C#7 you can return a list of tuples:

```
private IEnumerable<(string, string)> GetRowGroups(string columnName)
{
    return from table in _dataSetDataTable.AsEnumerable()
           group table by new { column1 = table[columnName] }
           into groupedTable
           select (groupedTable.Key.column1, groupedTable.Count());
}
```

You can even give the members of the tuple names:

```
private IEnumerable<(string groupName, string rowSpan)> GetRowGroups(string columnName)
{
    return from table in _dataSetDataTable.AsEnumerable()
           group table by new { column1 = table[columnName] }
           into groupedTable
           select (groupedTable.Key.column1, groupedTable.Count());
}
```

However you need [`System.ValueTuple`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.ValueTuple) from the Nuget Package Manager.

Anyway I suggest to give things a clear name that includes what their purpose is, in particular when this is part of a public API. Having said this you should consider to create a class that holds those properties and return a list of that type.