# Query LINQ with DDL DataTextField based on query LINQ and ObjectDataSource

Tags: c#, linq, drop-down-menu

I have a problem with this dropdownlist based on an ObjectDataSource

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" 
                DataSourceID="UserODS" DataTextField="LastName"
                DataValueField="IDUser">
</asp:DropDownList>

<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="UserODS" runat="server" 
                SelectMethod="GetListFullNameUsers" TypeName="DAL.AccessoDB">
</asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

The method is:

```
public List<String> GetListFullNameUsers()
{
   using (var context = new UChipDataContext())
   {
      return context.Users
                   .Select(c => new { c.LastName, c.FirstName })
                   .ToList()
                   .Select(c => String.Concat(c.LastName," ", c.FirstName))
                   .ToList(); 
   }
}
```

But I get this error:

DataBinding: 'System.String' does not contain a property with the name 'LastName'.

How can I solve?

Thanks in advance.

Luigi

Comment: Accept some of the answers on your previous questions. I hope no one answers this question until you start being an appreciative user.

Answer (score 1):

OK... the problem here is the following:

Your LINQ query returns a list of plain strings and so your databinding fails because those strings don't have a property called `LastName`.

One possible solution is to make the [anonymous type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531357.aspx) into a class as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1070557/114029) returning a strongly typed object with a property called `LastName` because you have `DataTextField="LastName"` and so your `DropDownList` does expect a property called `LastName`.

Comment: The anonymous type does contain a property LastName, but the query returns strings (String.Concat...).

Comment: @GertArnold: Sure, his method return type is wrong too I think. He should really return a type with a property called LastName because the datasource expects that. See the `DataTextField="LastName"`. Returning a list of strings I think this won't work but it's just a suspicion since I can't compile the code right now.

Answer (score 0):

Hrm why do you have multiple select / tolists??

Try this:

```
    return context.Users
                  .Select(c => string.Format("{0} {1}", c.LastName, c.FirstName))
                  .ToList();
```

Comment: The datasource expects a property called LastName and so I think this won't work. But your reasoning about the query is pretty good.