# return what type of data?

Tags: entity-framework-4

i have a method that return a data to fill datagridview (in a win form)
i use EF and i have inner join in my method and works fine and correct

what type of data should i have return until data source can accept it?

```
private ??? getData()
{ 
  using(var context =new context())
  {

     var query = from a in context.Table1
         join b in context.Table2 on a.Table1ID equals b.Table1Id
         select new 
         {
           Table1ID,
           a.A,
           b.Table2ID,
           b.B,  
         }; 

  return ???
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Return anonymous type?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/534690/return-anonymous-type)

Answer (score 0):

You should not use anonymous objects like that. You should create concrete class and return an object of it.

```
private Foo getData()
{ 
    using(var context =new context())
    {
        var query = from a in context.Table1
          join b in context.Table2 on a.Table1ID equals b.Table1Id
          select new Foo
          {
            A = Table1ID,
            B = a.A,
            C = b.Table2ID,
            D = b.B,  
          }; 

        return query;
    }
}
```

Anonymous types are used for other scenarios, e.g. accessing them inside the same scope.

See these answers:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/1070557/290343
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/534794/290343