# linq to sql using select new inside class file

Tags: asp.net, linq-to-sql

I usually use linq to sql with an ***IQueryable*** or ***IEnumerable*** to get data like this:

```
    public static IQueryable getSomething() 
    {
        var getit = from d in database.table select d;

        return getit;
    }
```

and it works fine but i am trying to use select new with it like this:

```
    public static IQueryable getSomething() 
    {
       var getit = from d in database.table select new 
       { 
          value1 = d.1,
          value2 = d.2
       };

    return getit;
}
```

> this is a sample code and not the actual code.

but that wont work, how do i do this?

thanks

Comment: possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/534690/linq-to-sql-return-anonymous-type

Comment: @rs. - didnt notice, voted to close

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot type any method in C# to be the explicit type of an anonymous types. They cannot be "named" so to speak and hence cannot appear in metadata signatures.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1070564/971839

First, You need to create a class like,

```
public class MyClass
    {

        public string Property1{get;set;}
        public string Property2{ get; set; }
    }
```

Then Replace Your Method with,

```
public static IEnumerable<MyClass> getSomething() 
        {
           var getit = from d in database.table select new 
          MyClass  { 
              Property1 = d.1,
              Property2 = d.2
                   };

        return getit;
    }
```

Comment: There is same question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1070526/how-to-return-anonymous-type-from-c-sharp-method-that-uses-linq-to-sql

Comment: no, i meant could you please explain further how this code works?

Comment: http://michaelsync.net/2008/03/06/c-30-tutorials-understanding-about-anonymous-types