# remove rows with no reference in other table

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework, linq

I am having trouble writing a linq query because I am new to it. I have two tables `RosterSummaryData_Subject_Local` and `RosterSummaryData_Subject_Local_Bands`.

`Subject_Local` contains `pkSummarySubjectLocalID` and `Subject_Local_Bands` contains a foreign key reference to that table (`fkSummarySubjectlocalID`). `Subject_Local` contains unused or orphaned rows that will never be used. What I want to do is remove the unused / orphaned rows if they do not exist in `Subject_Local_Bands`.

For example if we look at these sample tables:

```
RosterSummaryData_Subject_Local       RosterSummaryData_Subject_Local_Bands
pkSummarySubjectLocalID               pkSummarySubjectLocalBandID fkSummarySubjectLocalID  Score
1                                     1                           2                        10 
2                                     2                           4                        20
3                                     3                           5                        30
4
5
```

In these two tables you can see that the `Subject_Local.pkSummarySubjectLocalIDs` 1 and 3 in are never referenced in `Subject_Local_Bands`. I want to remove them from `Subject_Local`.

Here is my current LINQ code that does not work

```
var local = customerContext.RosterSummaryData_Subject_Local;
var localBands = customerContext.RosterSummaryData_Subject_Local_Bands;
IEnumerable<RosterSummaryData_Subject_Local> redundantSubjectLocalRows;

redundantSubjectLocalRows = from subjLocal in customerContext.RosterSummaryData_Subject_Local
                            join subjLocalBands in customerContext.RosterSummaryData_Subject_Local_Bands on 
                                 subjLocal.pkSummarySubjectLocalID equals subjLocalBands.fkSummarySubjectLocalID
                            where subjLocalBands.fkSummarySubjectLocalID != subjLocal.pkSummarySubjectLocalID
                            select subjLocal.pkSummarySubjectLocalID;

customerContext.RosterSummaryData_Subject_Local.RemoveRange(redundantSubjectLocalRows);
```

I want to use `RemoveRange` so I need to pass it an `IEnumerable` of my context class `RosterSummaryData_Subject_Local` but I don't know how to create that using a linq query that accomplishes the specified conditions. Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var local = customerContext.RosterSummaryData_Subject_Local;
var localBands = customerContext.RosterSummaryData_Subject_Local_Bands;
```

you should use [except](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb348938(v=vs.110).aspx). A except B returns all of the values that are in A but not in B.
we select all `local.pkSummarySubjectLocalID` except `localBands.fkSummarySubjectLocalID`, the result is all `pkSummarySubjectLocalID` that are in `local` but not in `localBands`.

```
var orphanedIds = local.Select(x => x.pkSummarySubjectLocalID)
                      .Except(localBands.Select(x => x.fkSummarySubjectLocalID));
```

then we join this result (`orphanedIds`) with `local` and get all of orphaned`local`s.

```
var orphaned = from l in local
      join id in orphanedIds on l.pkSummarySubjectLocalID equals id
      select l;
```

now it is time to remove all orphan `local`s.

```
local.RemoveRange(orphaned);
customerContext.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: I like your answer the most except it seems to only bring back the rows that are referenced in Subject_Local_Band.(these are the ids that I want to keep) I want the opposite of that. I flipped the intersect but I still had the same result.

Comment: the problem was a typo, I want to use except but i said intersect, fixed, this approach is done all with sql quesries in database side, other approaches are fetching lot of data from db.

Comment: Reluctantly I gotta upvote this answer which is definately sexier than my dull hammer approach :-) `Except()` huh? Learn something new everyday...

Answer (score 2):

Arguably inelegant, but this should be effective:

```
HashSet<int> unorphanedIds new HashSet<int>( 
    RosterSummaryData_Subject_Local_Bands
    .Select(b=>b.fkSummarySubjectLocalID));   

var toRemove = customerContext.RosterSummaryData_Subject_Local
    .Where(r=>!unorphanedIds.Contains(r.pkSummarySubjectLocalID));

customerContext.RosterSummaryData_Subject_Local.RemoveRange(toRemove);
customerContext.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 1):

Ryan,

You can create your RosterSummaryData_Subject_Local class using the following statement from your LINQ query.

```
public void TestMethod()
{
    DataSet lDataSet = new DataSet();

    var lOutput = (from lRosterSummaryBand in lDataSet.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
                   select new RosterSummaryData_Subject_Local 
                   {
                       //Assign the field value for each row to the model property specified.
                       //Make sure to use the correct data types specified from the data base.
                       pkSummarySubjectLocalID = lRosterSummaryBand.Field<System.Int64>("pkSummarySubjectLocalID") // Column name from DataTable / DataSet
                   }).ToList();//Make sure to set the output as an enumeration
}
```

The data is stored in a var collection but you can cast them as your object with ().

It is noteworthy to state that when LINQ assigns the values to this var collection it does it by reference not by value. Any changes made to the var will alter the DataTable/DataSet.

Alternatively you could also do the following. This will left join your two tables, assign them to models and only select the rows where your sub table is null/no value.

```
var lRowsMarketForDeletion = (from lSubjectLocal in lDataSet.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
                                      join lSubjectLocalbands in lDataSet.Tables[1].AsEnumerable() on lSubjectLocal.Field<System.Int64>("pkSummarySubjectLocalID") equals lSubjectLocalbands.Field<System.Int64>("pkSummarySubjectLocalID") into lJoinedGroup
                                      from lJoinedRow in lJoinedGroup.DefaultIfEmpty(new RosterSummaryData_Subject_Local { pkSummarySubjectLocalID = 0 })
                                      where lJoinedRow.pkSummarySubjectLocalID == 0
                                      select new RosterSummaryData_Subject_Local
                                      {
                                          pkSummarySubjectLocalID = lRosterSummaryBand.Field<System.Int64>("pkSummarySubjectLocalID")
                                      }).ToList();

customerContext.RosterSummaryData_Subject_Local.RemoveRange(lRowsMarketForDeletion);
```

References:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311040.aspx  Joining tables.

[linq to sql using select new inside class file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14130059/linq-to-sql-using-select-new-inside-class-file) Selecting into a new object for each row.

http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/linq/UXPF181012-SQL-Joins-with-C How left joins work.

Let me know if you need anything else.