# How to define a return type of an anonymous list

Tags: c#, list, class, types, return-value

I have the following method:

```
public static object GetBarChart(int dataValue)
{
using (var myEntities = new i96X_dataEntities())
{
  var myValues = (from values in myEntities.PointValues
                  where values.PointID == dataValue
                  select new
                  {
                     values.DataTime,
                     values.DataValue
                  }).ToList();
  }
  if (myValues.Count() != 0)
  {
    return myValues;
  }
  return null;
}
```

I can only return it as an object, because I can't work out how to define it as its type. When I debug it tells me the return type is:

{System.Collections.Generic.List<<>f__AnonymousType2< System.DateTime,double>>}

But I can't work out how to define that.

I have defined a class:

```
public class BarChart
{
  public DateTime Time { get; set; }
  public double Value { get; set; }
}
public class BarList
{
  public List<BarChart> BarL { get; set; } 
}
```

I presume that's correct. But if I now use BarList as my return type the compiler reads:

Cannot convert expression type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<{DataTime:System.DateTime, DataValue:double}>' to return type BarList'

I think the answer is just to define BarChart, then return List< BarChart>.

Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: Possible duplicate, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1070526/how-to-return-anonymous-type-from-c-sharp-method-that-uses-linq-to-sql

Comment: Incidentally, I would recommend _avoiding_ `.ToList()` unless you really mean to return a mutable datastructure.  `.ToArray` more efficient and somewhat safer in that it doesn't allow `Add` etc, and if you return it as  [`IReadOnlyList`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh192385.aspx) (.NET 4.5), then consumers won't be able to change entries without an explicit cast.

By preventing nonsensical actions you avoid bugs, and slightly reduce intellisense clutter to boot.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Return anonymous type?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/534690/return-anonymous-type)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function returns collection of Anonymous types. The anonymous type is defined in the LINQ expression.

If you know the type of which the PointValues collection in the DB is composed of then you can return directly that type.

If you have a class called for instance **Point** than change Anonymous constructor in the LINQ expression to a concrete one:

```
select new Point { Time = values.DataTime, Value = values.DataValue }
```

In that case your method will return a list of points. **IList<< Point >>**

Comment: I'm sorry, I would like to create a class of 'Point' but I can't see how I can make a type of List<DateTime, double>, as far as I can find out a list can only contain one type (obviously the anonymous class creates a list of 2 types, so that can't be true).

Comment: The list returned by the LINQ query is a List of Anonymous types. Each anonymous type than has two values. If for some reason you can't create your own class, than you can create an instance of Tupple or KeyValuePair - in other words you will get list of tupples.

Comment: I have edited my answer and added the class that I have defined, but I can't get it to work. I have the same problem if I try to create a Tuple, it says cannot convert etc to return type Tuple<DateTime, double>

Comment: I think I've gone one step too far in myclass definition, if I make my return type List<BarChart> I seem to be on the right track. Thanks for your help.

Comment: The method returns a `List<Point>`, of which `IList<Point>` is just one possible supertype.  There's probably no reason to hide the type of the return like in this case.  You wouldn't usually want to return a list from a public API anyhow, and in an internal API the type-hiding doesn't buy you much.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this?

```
public static IEnumerable<Tuple<DateTime, DataValue>>  GetBarChart(int dataValue)
  {
  return
    (
    from values in new i96X_dataEntities()
    where values.PointID == dataValue
    select new Tuple<DateTime, DataValue>(values.DataTime, values.DataValue)
    );
  }
```

Comment: If you create a constructor for `BarChart`, you can of course use those rather than `Tuple`s.  If you really need the results in an hard-typed list rather than an `IEnumerable`, you could create a new `BarList` with the output.

Comment: I can't get that to work as a list. If I try: select new List<Tuple<DateTime, double>>(values.DataTime, values.DataValue).ToList(); The compiler reads cannot resolve constructor. I create a list because I can have hundreds of points returned. Sorry, didn't read that right did I? I will try it now.