# Pass function as a parameter to Action

Tags: c#, delegates, action

I am trying to pass a method as an action, but it seems that that the casting is not per say.

This is how I am doing it:

```
public class RequestHandler<T> where T : struct
{
    public enum EmployeeRequests { BasicDetails, DependentsAndEmergencyContacts , MedicalHistory }

    protected Dictionary<T, Action> handlers = new Dictionary<T, Action>();

    protected EmployeeManagement empMgmnt = new EmployeeManagement();

    public void InitializeHandler(int employeeID)
    {

        this.AddHandler(EmployeeRequests.BasicDetails, () => empMgmnt.GetEmployeeBasicDetails(0));
    }

    public void AddHandler(T caseValue, Action action)
    {
        handlers.Add(caseValue, action);
    }

    public void RemoveHandler(T caseValue)
    {
        handlers.Remove(caseValue);
    }

    public void ExecuteHandler(T actualValue)
    {
        ExecuteHandler(actualValue, Enumerable.Empty<T>());
    }

    public void ExecuteHandler(T actualValue, IEnumerable<T> ensureExistence)
    {
        foreach(var val in ensureExistence)
            if (!handlers.ContainsKey(val))
                throw new InvalidOperationException("The case " + val.ToString() + " is not handled.");
        handlers[actualValue]();
    }
}
```

And this is my function that I am passing as a parameter:

```
public object GetEmployeeBasicDetails(int employeeID)
{
    return new { First_Name = "Mark", Middle_Initial = "W.", Last_Name = "Rooney"};
}
```

I am getting this error:

> Overloaded method has some invalid arguments.

**UPDATE**

This is how I manage to get around this:

```
public static class RequestHandler
{
    public enum EmployeeRequests { BasicDetails = 0, DependentsAndEmergencyContacts = 1 , MedicalHistory = 2 }

    private static Dictionary<EmployeeRequests, Func<object>> handlers = new Dictionary<EmployeeRequests, Func<object>>();

    public static void InitializeHandler(int employeeID)
    {
        Func<object> EmpBasicDetails = delegate { return EmployeeManagement.GetEmployeeBasicDetails(0); };
        AddHandler(EmployeeRequests.BasicDetails, EmpBasicDetails);
    }

    private static void AddHandler(EmployeeRequests caseValue, Func<object> empBasicAction)
    {
        handlers.Add(caseValue, empBasicAction);
    }

    public static void RemoveHandler(int caseValue)
    {
        var value = (EmployeeRequests)Enum.Parse(typeof(EmployeeRequests), caseValue.ToString());
        handlers.Remove(value);
    }

    public static object ExecuteHandler(int actualValue)
    {          
        var request = (EmployeeRequests)Enum.Parse(typeof(EmployeeRequests), actualValue.ToString());
        return handlers[(EmployeeRequests)request]();
    }
}
```

Comment: Where do you get the error?

Comment: An Action is specifically method with a void return type and no parameters. You cannot treat your method with an object return type and an int parameter as an Action. What you are trying to set is a method which matches a Func<int,object>.

Comment: You shouldn't return an anonymous object from `GetEmployeeBasicDetails`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1070526/how-to-return-anonymous-type-from-c-sharp-method-that-uses-linq-to-sql

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot pass a value-returning method as an `Action`, because `Action<T>` must take a parameter `T` and return nothing (i.e. `void`).

You can work around this by passing a lambda that calls your method and ignores its output:

```
Action empBasicAction = () => GetEmployeeBasicDetails(0);
```

Comment: Alright, I have got the code to work, but I want to return an object from the action that executes. Something similar to `object obj = empBasicAction();`

Comment: @faizanjehangir Then you need to replace `Action` with `Func<object>`. The rest of the code would stay the same.

Comment: Just did that. And it is working fine now, refer to the updated answer if anyone is interested.