# Bind & Format JSON result to Text Area

Tags: jquery, json, asp.net-mvc

What I would like to do is select a district from the dropdown list then have the district's: leaid, name, category, county, streetline1, streetline2, city, stateprovince, and postalcode shown on the same page below the dropdown using a JSON call to my controller which will query the database. I specify those columns because that is not all the columns that are in the District table. Right now I have a text area to show the result which should be formatted like so:

leaid   name   category   county   streetline 1  streetline2  city  etc...

---

0435    Orange .....     ......    ......    ......    .....

then under this i'm going to call a different query for another table and display all staff in that district in the same format.

What I'm having problems with is that nothing is showing up in my text area box. When it returns from the JsonResult, my code doesn't reach the `if(!response)` statement and ends up doing nothing.

If i need to explain more, then please let me know. I'm still new to some of MVC.

**Update:** I have tried using a valid id in the query string & it works fine when I select a district from the dropdown. But then after the query, using Firebug Lite for Chrome I get a 500 Internal Server error. Along with this: "System.InvalidOperationException: A circular reference was detected while serializing an object of type 'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.District_B959D005D9073957EF5DDF15D4B22821F90F‌​F068837E74B95429864C8DEB5D50'"

**My View with JSON call:**

```
<form>
    <div>
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedDistrict, Model.Districts, "----Select District----")
    </div>
    <div>
        @Html.TextArea("DistrictInformation", new { cols = 60, rows = 10 })
    </div>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript" src="~/scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var url = '@Url.Action("GetDistrictInfo", "District")';
    var info = $('#DistrictInformation');
    info.hide();
    $(document).on('change', '#SelectedDistrict', function () {
        info.val('').empty();          
        $.getJSON(url, { id: $(this).val() }, function (response) {
            if (!response) {
                return;
            }
            info.show();
            $.each(response, function (item) {
                info.append($.text(item.Text).val());
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

**My Controller with JsonResult & query:**

```
    public JsonResult GetDistrictInfo(string id)
    {
        var selectedDistrict = id;
        var district = getDistrict(selectedDistrict);
        return Json(district, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

    internal IQueryable<District> getDistrict(string id)
    {
        var query = from District in db.Districts
                    where District.leaID.Equals(id)
                    select District;
        return query;
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried opening the url in browser with a valid id in query string? Are there any errors in browser console? What is `$.text()` ?

Comment: @charlietfl Yes I have tried using a valid id in the query string & it works fine when I select a district from the dropdown. But then after the query, using Firebug Lite for Chrome I get a 500 Internal Server error. Along with this: "System.InvalidOperationException: A circular reference was detected while serializing an object of type 'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.District_B959D005D9073957EF5DDF15D4B22821F90FF068837E74B95429864C8DEB5D50'"

Comment: Suggest you modify subject of question then because issue isn't really about textarea or even jQuery related it's a server side problem. Also update question with those errors

Comment: @charlietfl alright I updated my question with my error.

Comment: The error means that `District` contains a property which is a type that containing a property which is typeof `District` (creating a circular reference error). Instead, return an anonymous object containing only the properties of `District` that you need in the view.

Comment: @StephenMuecke so I went around searching for returning an anonymous objects and I came across a post that shows how to turn the anonymous object into a Class. Would that be along the lines of what you were thinking? 

Link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1070526/how-to-return-anonymous-type-from-c-sharp-method-that-uses-linq-to-sql

Comment: There is no need to create a class (your sending data to a browser which has no knowledge of what a c# class is). If you need to return the (say) `ID` and `Name` properties of `District` then its just `var data = district .Select(d => new { ID = d.ID, Name = d.Name }; return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);` Just return only those properties of `District` that you need in the view.