# How to return the result set with columns with Linq

Tags: linq, linq-to-entities, intellisense

I have a function inside a class that will run a Linq to Entities query (or any type of Linq query actually), and it's gonna return 2 columns in the resultset. I would like to return an object to whoever is calling my function that will allow Intellisense to know what I have returned.
Let me explain. If I have a function like this:

```
public static IQueryable GetInfo(MyEntityModel oEntityModel)
{
  var query =
    (from t in oEntityModel.Table1
     from u in t.Table2
     where t.Status == true &&
     u.Status == true
     select new
     {
       t.Column1,
       u.Column2
     })
  return query;
}
```

What can (should) I put instead of IQueryable so that whoever calls my GetInfo function, will get Intellisense from the resultset, and show that it has a Column1 and Column2?

```
var linqresult = ClsLinqTeste.GetInfo(oEntityModel);
if (linqresult.Column1 == 1)
{
  foreach (var oItem in linqresult)
  {
    .. do stuff...
  }
}
```

Tks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Return anonymous type?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/534690/return-anonymous-type)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot return an anonymous type from a function, they are strictly "inline" classes.  When you return it, the foreach loop will only be able to interpret the result as an plain object.  I guess you could use reflection to query the property names and values, however it seems much more straight forward to define a data transfer type to hold the results.

See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2293622/how-to-return-multiple-classes-as-iqueryablet), and this [blog post](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/05/15/new-orcas-language-feature-anonymous-types.aspx).

So you could create a simple struct or class:

```
public class MyDataResult
{
    public object Column1 { get; set; }
    public object Column2 { get; set; }
}
```

Then modify your query in the function:

```
public static IQueryable<MyDataResult> GetInfo(MyEntityModel oEntityModel)
{
  var query =
    (from t in oEntityModel.Table1
     from u in t.Table2
     where t.Status == true &&
     u.Status == true
     select new MyDataResult
     {
       Column1 = t.Column1,
       Column2 = u.Column2
     })
  return query;
}
```

Something like that should work.  Note that I used "object" for the properties in MyDataResult.  I don't know the types of the columns you are returning, you should use the actual types in order to get full intellisense.

Comment: I see... I thought there might be a way to create a "temporary" class, so that I could pass the result. I would need to actually create a class, fill an array or list with it, and return that as resultset of my function, correct?

Comment: I marked @ravadre as the answer because of the coded explanation, but I've upvoted your answer as well. Tks so much for your answer and time

Comment: niiiiiicce... that was EXACTLY what I wanted to do. After the code, you got the answer! Tks so much for sharing the knowledge. ;-)

Comment: I actually need to implement Ienumerable on MyDataResult to do this, right?

Comment: Sorry... my mistake.. I didn't notice the Column1 =  and Column2 = . Tks! Worked like a charm! Awesome

Answer (score 2):

You are returning a collection of anonymous types, they will be casted to objects, so when you try to iterate over them, altough they will be your objects (and they will contain your properties) at compile time they will be casted to objects:

```
foreach (var x in ClsLinqTeste.GetInfo(oEntityModel))
{
  //x is an Object
}
```

You can read more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1329672/is-there-a-way-to-return-anonymous-type-from-method).

If you want to have intellisense, I suggest you create a custom class they will hold your properties and return not an anonymous type (using `new {}`) but object of your class (`new MyClass(prop1, prop2)`). You also need to change signature of your method, so it returns `IQueryable<YourClass>` and not just plain non-generic `IQueryable`.

Comment: Tks so much for your time and answer

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, creating a new type to hold the two columns is usually the best option.

But if, for some reason, you don't want to do that and you are using .Net 4.0, you can use `Tuple`:

```
public static IQueryable<Tuple<Column1Type, Column2Type>>
    GetInfo(MyEntityModel oEntityModel)
{
  return from …
         select Tuple.Create(t.Column1, u.Column2);
}


var linqresult = ClsLinqTeste.GetInfo(oEntityModel);
foreach (var oItem in linqresult)
  Console.WriteLIne(oItem.Item1, oItem.Item2);
```

Comment: Nice suggestion. Didn't know I could do that

Answer (score 0):

When you return your resultset AsQueryable, the app is already able to give you intellisense, however in your example, you must specify either .FirstOrDefault if you know your collection will only have a single row, or iterate over your collection to get the items from it, like so:

This is what you're doing:

```
var linqresult = ClsLinqTeste.GetInfo(oEntityModel);
if (linqresult.Column1 == 1)
{
  ..do stuff...
}
```

This is how you should do it:

```
var linqresult = ClsLinqTeste.GetInfo(oEntityModel);

foreach(var item in linqresult)
{
  if (item.Column1 == 1)
  {
    ..do stuff...
  }
}
```

You must iterate over linqresult because when you query with link, it returns a result set, even if it just has one column. As with any collection, your data columns aren't available on the whole result set, only with individual items.

Comment: I think you are forgetting that item will have type of object, because method is returning an IQueryable interface. So you won't be able to access it's property just like that.

Comment: Hey.. tks for the help.. I was actually my mistake when I type the question. I am actually using the foreach, but on the item.XXX , the Column1 doesn't show up

Comment: because this method returns IQueryable, and you can check [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.iqueryable.aspx) to see, that it only allows to enumerate over Object type. So item in your foreach loop will be of Object type, and Object does not contain .Column1 property.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to strongly typed enumerate a non-generic IEnumerable (`IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()` instead of `IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator<T>()`) you can use the Cast<>() extension, like so

```
 var myquery = GetQueryable();

 for (var item in myquery.Cast<MyDataType>())
 {
       // use item.Column1 directly and strongly typed with intellisense
 }
```