# What is the return type for a anonymous linq query select? What is the best way to send this data back?

Tags: linq, silverlight, linq-to-entities, silverlight-4.0

This is a basic question. I have the basic SL4/RIA project set up and I want to create a new method in the domain service and return some data from it. I am unsure the proper easiest way to do this.. Should I wrap it up in a ToList()? I am unclear how to handle this anonymous type that was create.. what is the easiest way to return this data?

```
 public IQueryable<ApplicationLog> GetApplicationLogsGrouped()
    {
        var x = from c in ObjectContext.ApplicationLogs
                let dt = c.LogDate
                group c by new { y = dt.Value.Year, m = dt.Value.Month, d = dt.Value.Day } into mygroup
                select new { aaa = mygroup.Key, ProductCount = mygroup.Count() };

        return x;


        // return this.ObjectContext.ApplicationLogs.Where(r => r.ApplicationID < 50);
    }
```

Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<AnonymousType#1>' to 'System.Linq.IQueryable<CapRep4.Web.ApplicationLog>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)   58  20  CapRep4.Web

Comment: ok. .so it seems I either make my own class or key/value..

What if I am returning more than 2 values?? Is that a case for using Tuples? (I always wanted a reason to use Tuples)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Return anonymous type?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/534690/return-anonymous-type)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An anonymous type is like any other class, but it's created by the compiler. What the compiler generates is something like:

```
class AnonymousType1 {
  public AnonymousType2 Key { get; set; }
  public int ProductCount { get; set; }
}

class AnonymousType2 {
  public int y { get; set; }
  public int m { get; set; }
  public int d { get; set; }
}
```

Those classes are not accessible to you so you have no choice but to use a custom class matching the definition of Anonymous1 instead if you want to keep strong typing. You'll then use it like this: `new MyClass { Key = myGroup.Key, ProductCount = mygroup.Count() }`.

Comment: I sort of understand. but then what would the signature of the method be ?

Answer (score 3):

Try using a KeyValuePair

```
public IQueryable<KeyValuePair<ApplicationLog,int>> GetApplicationLogsGrouped()
{
  var x = from c in ObjectContext.ApplicationLogs
          let dt = c.LogDate
          group by c  into mygroup
          select new KeyValuePair<ApplicationLog,int>( mygroup.Key,mygroup.Count()) ;

  return x;

  // return this.ObjectContext.ApplicationLogs.Where(r => r.ApplicationID < 50);
}
```

Comment: public IQueryable<KeyValuePair<ApplicationLog, int>> GetApplicationLogsGrouped()
        {
            var x = from c in ObjectContext.ApplicationLogs
                    let dt = c.LogDate
                    group c by new { y = dt.Value.Year, m = dt.Value.Month, d = dt.Value.Day } into mygroup
                    select new KeyValuePair<ApplicationLog, int>( mygroup.Key, mygroup.Count());
         
            return x;


          
Argument 1: cannot convert from 'AnonymousType#1' to 'CapRep4.Web.ApplicationLog'

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to create your own class for the projection.

```
public class ApplicationLogStatistic
{
    public ApplicationLog ApplicationLog { get; internal set; }
    public int ProductCount { get; internal set; }
}
```

...

```
public IQueryable<ApplicationLogStatistic> GetApplicationLogsGrouped()
{
    var x = // OP's code, except for select
        select new ApplicationLogStatistic 
                  { 
                       ApplicationLog = mygroup.Key, 
                       ProductCount = mygroup.Count() 
                  };
    return x;
}
```

Comment: public IQueryable<ApplicationLogStatistic> GetApplicationLogsGrouped2()
        {
            var x = from c in ObjectContext.ApplicationLogs
                    let dt = c.LogDate
                    group c by new { y = dt.Value.Year, m = dt.Value.Month, d = dt.Value.Day } into mygroup
                    select new ApplicationLogStatistic
                    {
                        oApplicationLog = mygroup.Key,
                        ProductCountz = mygroup.Count()
                    };

            return x;
        }

Comment: Cannot implicitly convert type 'AnonymousType#1' to 'CapRep4.Web.ApplicationLog' 80 43 CapRep4.Web

Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<CapRep4.Web.ApplicationLogStatistic>' to 'System.Linq.IQueryable<CapRep4.Web.ApplicationLogStatistic>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?) 84 20 CapRep4.Web

Comment: Application Log is a ENTITY OBJECT but mygroup.key is a Tkey?