# Silverlight - LinqToEntities - How Do I Return Anonymous Types

Tags: c#, silverlight, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, anonymous-types

I'm not sure if I'm going at this the right way.  I have a Silverlight app and using Entity Framework for a lot of it.  I have Two Entities mapped to my database:  Header and Details.  I want to submit a left outter join to get all headers and details counts - even if the header record has no detail record.  Here is the Linq Query I want to run from the Client:

```
var query =
      from head in storeContext.Headers
      join detail in storeContext.Details
      on head.HeadId equals details.HeadId
      into group
      select new 
      {
        Desc = head.Description,
        MyCount = group.Count()
      };
```

Since this is Silverlight, I need to build my query, then submit it to the server with the `storeContext.Load<T>()` method from my Domain Service (Context on the client).  Because this method is expecting a type, I don't know how to structure the call to return an anonymous type as I am dong above?

Am I doing this all wrong?  Should I be using an Invoke method for something like this?  If so, how and where do I define the type I want to return?

Is someone could point me in the right direction I would really appriciate it.

Thanks... Scott

Comment: you can't return annonymous types, it doesn't matter if you are in WCF RIA, or whatever

Comment: possible duplicate of [Return anonymous type?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/534690/return-anonymous-type)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't return an anonymous type. They are, by necessity, local to the current scope.

Your query looks correct, but you will need to return a named type:

```
var query =
      from head in storeContext.Headers
      join detail in storeContext.Details
      on head.HeadId equals details.HeadId
      into group
      select new MyHelper // SPECIFY A CLASS HERE
      {
        Desc = head.Description,
        MyCount = group.Count()
      };
```

Your query method will need to return an `IEnumerable<MyHelper>`:

```
public IEnumerable<MyHelper> GetInfo()
{
    var query ...

    return query;
}
```

Comment: Can't you return an anonymous type by wrapping it with `dynamic`?

Comment: @Jeff - I haven't played with `dynamic` yet so I don't know.

Comment: Me neither, but I'm curious now. Not that I think it's necessarily a good idea, but interesting none-the-less.

Comment: Thanks for the hlep.  This solved my problem.  Question:  Is it better to create the helper class on both the clinet and the server, or just add the Using to the client?

Comment: @Scott, you should just be able to create the class on the server and if you create a metadata class it will get created on the client automatically.

Answer (score 1):

You can never return a value that is an instance of an anonymous type from a method.  Anonymous types are *always* local to the method.  If you want to return a type over WCF you're going to have to write the class yourself, rather than relying on anonymous types.