# What is the return type of my linq query?

Tags: .net, linq

I have two tables A & B. I can fire Linq queries & get required data for individual tables.
As i know what each of the tables will return as shown in example. 
But, when i join both the tables i m not aware of the return type of the Linq query. This problem can be solved by creating a class which will hold ID,Name and Address properties inside it. but,everytime before writing a join query depending on the return type i will have to create a class which is not a convinient way
Is there any other mathod available to achieve this

```
  private IList<A> GetA()
    {
        var query = from a in objA
                    select a;
        return query.ToList();
    }

    private IList<B> GetB()
    {
        var query = from b in objB
                    select b;
        return query.ToList();
    }

    private IList<**returnType**?> GetJoinAAndB()
    {
        var query = from a in objA
                    join b in objB
                    on a.ID equals b.AID
                    select new { a.ID, a.Name, b.Address };
        return query.ToList();
    }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/534690/linq-to-sql-return-anonymous-type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value you generate is called Anonymous Type and you can return it unless you return `object` like:

```
private object GetJoinAAndB()
{
    var query = from a in objA
                join b in objB
                on a.ID equals b.AID
                select new { a.ID, a.Name, b.Address };
    return query.ToList();
}
```

There are two good solutions:
1. is to generate a class to match the output and generate it like Kobi solution
2. if you are using .net 4 you can return a `dynamic` type like

```
private dynamic GetJoinAAndB()
{
    var query = from a in objA
                join b in objB
                on a.ID equals b.AID
                select new { a.ID, a.Name, b.Address };
    return query.ToList();
}
```

then you can use it later. You can search the internet about the advantage of using `dynamic` keyword.

Comment: `dynamic` is meant to be used with COM objects, not as replacement for proper design. It will make the development very difficult - you lose intellisense, and all compilation errors will turn into **runtime errors**. `object` is only a little better, as you're limited to invalid casting runtime errors. At the very least, test a lot.

Comment: Yes I know, u're totally right but sometimes although I'm against this, you have to use to satisfy your need.

Answer (score 14):

You've created an anonymous class - you can't really return it. A simple solution is to add a class to represent your type.

For example:

```
public class UserWithAddress
{
    public UserWithAddress(int id, string name, string address)
    {
        ID = id;
        Name = name;
        Address = address;
    }

    // you may have your own types here
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public String Address { get; set; }
}
```

And then:

```
private IList<UserWithAddress> GetJoinAAndB()
{
    var query = from a in objA
                join b in objB
                on a.ID equals b.AID
                select new UserWithAddress(a.ID, a.Name, b.Address);
    return query.ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Like Kobi said.

If you do not want to create a class specifically for this case, you can use a `Tuple`. Only supported .Net 4 though.

Answer (score 2):

As you have created an anonymous(**Anonymous types are generated by the compiler, so we cannot know the type name in our codes**) class so that you can not return it.Create a separate class with three properties Id,Name and Address then returned it.

```
  public class Contact
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public string Address { get; set; }

        }

 private IList<Contact> GetJoinAAndB()
    {
        var query = from a in objA
                    join b in objB
                    on a.ID equals b.AID
                    select new Contact{ a.ID, a.Name, b.Address };
        return query.ToList();
    }
```