# Incorrect Model Type from my View

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, linq, entity-framework, razor

I'm getting an error that says:

The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1[System.Collections.Generic.List`1[RTDOTNET.Song]]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[RTDOTNET.Song]'.

It sounds like I'm using the wrong model type but I'm not sure what type I should be using.

Here's my controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {

            var theSongList = from u in db.Users
                              join s in db.Songs
                              on u.UserId equals s.UserId
                              into newSongList
                              select newSongList.ToList();

            ViewBag.Message = "Current Song";

            return View(theSongList);
        }
```

This is the view:

```
@model List<RTDOTNET.Song>
```

Comment: I recommend you to use DB queries inside a repository class

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are returning a list of queries you want a list of results so change it to:

```
var theSongList = (from u in db.Users
                   join s in db.Songs
                   on u.UserId equals s.UserId
                   into newSongList
                   select newSongList).ToList();
```

Adding () will give you the results.

Comment: Hmm..  Tried adding the parentheses and still getting the same error

Comment: If you put a break point on the return and add a watch on theSongList.  What do you get in your list, before the methods returns?

Comment: You need to change that query to somthing besides a JOIN if you want to return List<Song>.  Right now it is trying to pass an object of a different type because when you do a join on two different types, your  result is no longer List<Song>.

Comment: So are you saying it's not possible to return a JOIN query as a list?  Is there a better alternative for doing this?

Comment: No, what I am saying, is that your View is expecting System.Collections.Generic.List`1[RTDOTNET.Song] and your Join is not returning a List of Songs, it is returning a Join of two objects which is not compatible with your typed View.  So you either have to change 1) what your view expects, 2) your query to return what your view wants or 3) write some code after the query to get a list of Songs.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5013472/what-is-the-return-type-of-my-linq-query, this post will help with dealing with joins and LINQ, but I think you could accomplish your goal without a join.

Comment: Thanks, I should be able to get what I need from there.  Basically I have 2 tables...  1 with Username and UserID, the 2nd has userID as a foreign key and includes information about songs.  I want to display the username instead of userID when I list all songs.  Usually I would use a JOIN to display this information but is there a better way to do this with entity?

Comment: The join would be fine for that case.  It just means you have change the data type associated with your view.  A join returns an anonymous type.  The link I provided should guide you in the right direction.