# Joining 2 table with LINQ to Entities

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, linq, entity-framework, razor

I have two tables, for Users and Songs.  I need to JOIN them both on the UserID column and return a list to the view.  I tried writing an anonymous type but I'm getting an error about:

'Only parameterless constructors and initializers are supported in LINQ to Entities.'

How can I JOIN and return to list?

```
 public class User
    {
        [Key]
        public virtual Guid UserId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public virtual String Username { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public virtual String Email { get; set; }

        [Required, DataType(DataType.Password)]
        public virtual String Password { get; set; }

}





 public class Song
    {
        public int SongId { get; set; }

        public virtual Guid UserId { get; set; }

        public string SongTitle { get; set; }

    }
```

I tried implementing a method like this one here:

[What is the return type of my linq query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5013472/what-is-the-return-type-of-my-linq-query)

The query I ended up with was:

```
var query = from u in db.Users
                        join s in db.Songs
                        on u.UserId equals s.UserId
                        select new HomeSongList(s.SongId, s.UserId, u.Username);


            return View(query.ToList());
```

Comment: can you show what you have tried?

Comment: It seems to be code first : why do you have "public virtual Guid UserID" and not "public virtual User" in Song class ? I don't think a FK needs to be virtual, a Reference property does (in a lazy world)

Comment: Good catch, I didn't even notice that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use parameterized constructors but you can use initializers, if you change your select to the following it should work.

```
select new HomeSongList{SongId=s.SongId, UserId=s.UserId, Username=u.Username};
```

Note that this will require that `HomeSongList` has a parameterless constructor and writable properties.

Answer (score 2):

Well the error message is rather clear, no ?

You try to create a new HomeSongList in an linq2entity query (which will be translated in sql  : not possible)

With the "User property" correction, you should make

```
var query = db.Songs.Select(s => new{
                       songId = s.SongId, 
                       userId = s.User.UserId, 
                       userName = s.User.Username})
                     .ToList()
                     .Select(x => new HomeSongList(x.songId, x.userId, x.userName);
```

or with your actual code

```
var query = (from u in db.Users
                        join s in db.Songs
                        on u.UserId equals s.UserId
                        select new {
                          songId = s.SongId, 
                          userId = s.UserId, 
                          userName = u.Username
                         })//new anonymous object is possible in linq2entities
                        .ToList()
                        .Select(x => new HomeSongList(x.songId, x.userId, x.userName);
```

Comment: How would I strongly type my view?  It returns a list, so wouldn't I want something like  @model List<RTDOTNETMEMBER.Models.HomeSongList>

Comment: Sure. List or IList with this query.

Comment: By the way, look at @Guvante answer, it's the best way (with the constraints given).

Comment: Hmm..  IList and List Give me "The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectListIterator`2[<>f__AnonymousType1`9"

The page does render if I use IEnumerable