# How do I break up my data so I can feed it through to my view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq

I am an absolute beginner to asp.net and I've got quite a complex problem, specifically how do I get at the data I've just got from the database. Below is my query and the start of dealing with the data.

```
        var brandslist = from brand in brandDB.brands
                         join brand_family in brandDB.brand_family
                         on brand.brand_family_id equals brand_family.bf_id
                         orderby brand_family.brand_family_name,
                                 brand.priority,
                                 brand.genre_id
                         select new
                         {
                             brand_family.brand_family_name,
                             brand.priority,
                             brand.roll_image
                         };

        var viewModel = new BrandIndexViewModel{
            Brands = brandslist.ToList()
        };
```

I'm used to doing things with PHP, not asp which is why I'm so absolutely stumped. I do have one previous database call that works but i'm only getting one thing from the database whereas here I'm trying to get multiple items from the database. I suppose my question here is how do I make the data accessible to my view class?

Thanks to anyone who helps me out on this as I'm sure it's a fairly basic problem.

EDIT

Below is the error message I'm getting on compile:

Error   1   Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List'  C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\hcd\hcd\Controllers\HomeController.cs    35  26  hcd

EDIT 2

Just to confirm I am using ASP MVC 2.

EDIT 3

This is my brand index view model (but i'm already seeing a possible problem with it)

```
public class BrandIndexViewModel
{
    public List<string> Priority { get; set; }
    public List<string> FamilyName { get; set; }
    public List<string> RollImage { get; set; }
    public List<string> Brands { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: Seems ok, is it giving any error or just don't work?

Answer (score 2):

The root of your problem is that your LINQ query returns an anonymous type, but you're assigning to Brands which is a `List<string>`. Ultimately, you need to get the strings you want. I'm going to assume that "brand_family_name" is the data that you want to go into the `List<string> Brands`.

```
var viewModel = new BrandIndexViewModel{
            Brands = brandslist.Select(b => b.brand_family_name).ToList() // Or whichever property you want to use to populate List<string> Brands
        };
```

Comment: See also the "DogWithBreed" example at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/534690/linq-to-sql-return-anonymous-type

Comment: Thanks for this. I've given the first example a try and it seems to working better than the second example but i get errors about implcitly converting types from int (in the first case) and string (in the other two) to Error System.Collections.Generic.List<string>'.

Comment: If you could post the definition of BrandIndexViewModel and of whatever type the Brands list contains, it would be helpful for matching up the types.

Comment: +1 for being the only one to even mention the crucial anonymous types (the rest was just fuzz). sigh

Comment: @sehe Thanks. Without knowing what the target types are, fuzzy guesses to demonstrate the concept were as far as I could go.

Comment: I meant: "the rest" as in the other answers :) I was gonna type your answer - but as always I do a incremental search `/anon`, and little did I know your post was gonna be the only hit ... eeeeck

Comment: added in the brandindexviewmodel for your consideration

Comment: I've edited my answer to be more specific and concise. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the other answers, you don't specify what you want in the `Brands` list of your ViewModel (it would be most logical to have something like `brand.Name`). Posting your `brand` and `brand_family` classes could clarify this.

If I understand correctly, you basically need a list of `Brands` to display in your View. In that case it would be neater to group `FamilyName`, `Priority`, `RollImage` and `Brand` into one object and have a list of those in your ViewModel:

```
public class BrandIndexViewModel
{
    public List<BrandIndexItem> BrandIndexItems { get; set; }
}

public class BrandIndexItem
{
    public string Priority { get; set; }
    public string FamilyName { get; set; }
    public string RollImage { get; set; }
    public string Brand { get; set; }
}
```

In that case you won't have to do a `Select` in order to populate every list. Instead, you can project the query results directly onto your ViewModel. Here is what the code should look like with the join:

```
    var viewModel = new BrandIndexViewModel
                    {
                        BrandIndexItems = 
                           (from brand in brandDB.brands
                            join brand_family in brandDB.brand_family
                            on brand.brand_family_id equals brand_family.bf_id
                            orderby brand_family.brand_family_name,
                                    brand.priority,
                                    brand.genre_id
                            select new BrandIndexItem
                            {
                                FamilyName = brand_family.brand_family_name,
                                Priority = brand.priority,
                                RollImage = brand.roll_image,
                                Brands = brand.name // ?
                            }).ToList()
                    }
```

Furthermore, you mention using a Database, but you don't mention whether you are using an ORM such as EF or LINQ-to-SQL. If you are using one of them, it would really help if you could post a screenshot of your model. Meanwhile, according to your code, it does seem that you have a one-to-many relationship between `brand_family` and `brand`, so if you are using an ORM, you probably have a navigational property `brand.brand_family`. In that case, you won't need a `join` in your LINQ query:

```
    var viewModel = new BrandIndexViewModel
                    {
                        BrandIndexItems = 
                           (from brand in brandDB.brands
                            orderby brand.brand_family.brand_family_name,
                                    brand.priority,
                                    brand.genre_id
                            select new BrandIndexItem
                            {
                                FamilyName = brand.brand_family.brand_family_name,
                                Priority = brand.priority,
                                RollImage = brand.roll_image,
                                Brands = brand.name // ?
                            }).ToList()
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume that you are using ASP.NET MVC.

To access the brandslist variable from your view, pass it in from the controller using the model parameter.  For example:

```
ActionResult ListAllBrands()
{
    var brandslist = from brand in brandDB.brands
                         join brand_family in brandDB.brand_family
                         on brand.brand_family_id equals
                         brand_family.bf_id
                         orderby brand_family.brand_family_name,
                         brand.priority,
                         brand.genre_id
                         select new
                         {
                             brand_family.brand_family_name,
                             brand.priority,
                             brand.roll_image
                         };

    return View("List", brandslist);
}
```

Then in your view, there will be a variable called "Model" which will contain this value.  You can then iterate through each record in the .ASPX code using a for/each loop.