# Converting Anonymous Type To Nominal Type

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, c#-4.0

I have a method here that should return a Rpt_IncidentWithConfirm object but I have no clue how to easily convert it to one. The only way I know how it do do what I have below which is very inefficient.

```
    public Rpt_IncidentWithConfirm GetIncident(string IncidentID)
    {
        db = new IncidentsDataContext();

        var incident = (from i in db.Rpt_IncidentWithConfirms
                       join d in db.DropDowns on i.incidentType equals d.value
                       where i.incidentID == Convert.ToInt32(IncidentID)
                       select new
                       {
                           i, d.text
                       }).SingleOrDefault();
        Rpt_IncidentWithConfirm r = new Rpt_IncidentWithConfirm();
        // I didn't want to have to type all this here because I have too many fields to map.

        r.bhaIncident = incident.i.bhaIncident;
        r.bitType = incident.i.bitType;
        r.Bottom_Connection = incident.i.Bottom_Connection;
        // And so on.


        return r;
    }
```

Comment: Anonymous types are as strong as named types, they just don't have a name that's all

Comment: @Rune Excellent point. It's usually *nominal* vs. anonymous types.

Comment: What's "very inefficient" about that?

Comment: I have about 50 different fields that I would have to map together so it would take forever to type the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually used the answer linked below to solve my problem.  It isn't exactly what I wanted to do but I don't have to type everything manually now.
[Return anonymous type results?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/534690/linq-to-sql-return-anonymous-type/534794#534794)

```
        public class IncidentWithDropDown
    {
        public Rpt_IncidentWithConfirm Incident { get; set; }
        public string IncidentTypeText { get; set; }
    }
    public IncidentWithDropDown GetIncident(string IncidentID)
    {
        db = new IncidentsDataContext();

        var incident = (from i in db.Rpt_IncidentWithConfirms
                       join d in db.DropDowns on i.incidentType equals d.value
                       where i.incidentID == Convert.ToInt32(IncidentID)
                       select new IncidentWithDropDown()
                       {
                           Incident = i,
                           IncidentTypeText = d.text
                       }).SingleOrDefault();

        return incident;
    }
```

Comment: Small update, you can drop the constructor () when using the initializers: 'select new IncidentWithDropDown { ... }'

Answer (score 3):

You can instantiate the `Rpt_IncidentWithConfirm` object directly in the query expression and only refer to the database values you need:

```
var incident = (from i in db.Rpt_IncidentWithConfirms
                join d in db.DropDowns on i.incidentType equals d.value
                where i.incidentID == Convert.ToInt32(IncidentID)
                select new Rpt_IncidentWithConfirm
                {
                   bhaIncident = i.bhaIncident
                 , bitType = i.bitType
                 , Bottom_Connection = i.Bottom_Connection
                }).SingleOrDefault();
```

Comment: This wouldn't solve the problem I have now. I am trying to find a way to avoid doing "bhaIncident = i.bhaIncident" since I need every column in the database.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `anonymus type` you can use the type you have to return

```
 select new Rpt_IncidentWithConfirm 
                   {
                       // set all properties you need
                   }).SingleOrDefault();
```

Edit:
If your query is on collection type you want to return you can simply use result of query:

```
 return db.Rpt_IncidentWithConfirms.Where( ... ).FirstOrDefault();
```

or if u need value of text use :

```
//do something with incident.Text
return incident.i;
```

Answer (score 0):

you are not required to create an anonymous type in the select just create an object of the the named type instead

```
public Rpt_IncidentWithConfirm GetIncident(string IncidentID)
    {
        db = new IncidentsDataContext();

        var return (from i in db.Rpt_IncidentWithConfirms
                       join d in db.DropDowns on i.incidentType equals d.value
                       where i.incidentID == Convert.ToInt32(IncidentID)
                       select new Rpt_IncidentWithConfirm(){

                           bhaIncident =i.bhaIncident,
                           bitType = i.bitType,
                           Bottom_Connection = i.Bottom_Connection,
                           // And so on.
                        }).SingleOrDefault()
    }
```