# LINQ to Sql using anonymous types?

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

For years i've been under the impression that with the advent of [anonymous types in C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384061.aspx), e.g.:

```
// anon is compiled as an anonymous type
var anon = new { Name = "Terry", Age = 34 };
```

Linq to Sql is able to construct anonymous typed objects from a results set, e.g.:

***Example (hypothetical syntax)***:

```
var activeUsers = 
        from u in ConnectionStrings:Northwind.Users
        where u.IsActive = 1
        select UserName, FullName, Email, Description
```

And now i can operate on this *collection*, e.g.:

```
foreach (var u in activeUsers)
{
    AddToListView(u.UserName, u.FullName, u.Email);
}
```

Is this simple, powerful, easy to use example a fantasy?

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/534690/linq-to-sql-return-anonymous-type

Comment: It looks like without a correctly setup, and maintained, `DataContext` it cannot be done; Linq is unwilling to connect to the database at design time to get schema information. So the syntax `db.Users` fails to compile since there is no `Users` property of the `DataContext` object **db**.

Comment: Surely interesting, [but on topic here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130444/is-there-a-proper-stack-exchange-site-for-language-specific-feature-requests)? It's hard to answer your question other than: yes, a fantasy, for now.

Comment: Note that **Entity Framework** is happy to give you an `IQueryable<anonymous type>`, along the lines of `var q = context.Clients.Select(c => new { Id = c.ClientId });`

Comment: @AakashM i started to look at what is required to perform a `LEFT JOIN` in Linq, and now whatever you wrote does (`Clients`? `c`? *equals or greater than*? `Id`?). i think i'll just back away slowly. i got [the answer to my question through SteveKonves's linked answer](http://justlikemozarella.files.wordpress.com/2012/03/one-does-not-simply.jpg?w=468&h=276).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Linq to Sql requires a `DataContext` and associated database metadata before it can query a database.

It is also not able to "use" a `web.config` connection strings entry (as without static design-time metadata it cannot compile the query.