# Unable to cast object of type in MVC 3.0 Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, linq, razor

I am new MVC 3.0 Razor.  I am using LINQ to get the details of profiles.

In the controller i am using

```
  var q = from m in networks.Entities
                    join o in networks.EntityTypes on m.EntityTypeIdFk 
                    where m.Status == 1
                    orderby m.EntityName
                    select new { m.EntityName,m.EntityDescription,o.EntityTypeName };

            ViewBag.EntitiesName = q.ToList();
```

on the View i m using

```
@foreach (var res in ViewBag.EntitiesName)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@res.EntityName</td>
            <td>@res.EntityDescription</td>
            <td>@res.EntityTypeName</td>
        </tr>
    }
```

in the @res i m getting the resultant array. But still i m getting error "Unable to cast object of type"

Please Help me to resolve this.

Thanks,
Saloni

Comment: Unable to cast object of type '<>f__AnonymousType3`5[System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String]'

Comment: u have the model passed to the view?

Comment: yes i m using @model MVCSAMPLE.Models.Entities on the top of the View

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i resolved my problem by using

```
select new MVCSAMPLE.Models.Entities 
{ 
    EntityName = m.EntityName, 
    EntityDescription = m.EntityDescription, 
    EntityTypeName = o.EntityTypeName
}
```

Thanks to all.

Answer (score 0):

```
public ActionResult SomeAction()
    {
         //ur linq here
        var model = q.ToList();
        return View(model);
    }
```

in view

```
@model List<MVCSAMPLE.Models.Entities> 
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>@item.EntityName</td>
        <td>@item.EntityDescription</td>
        <td>@item.EntityTypeName</td>
        <td>@item.IndustryName</td>
        <td>@item.Name</td>
    </tr>
}
```

Just for example. Try to specify the type of ur list.
Another way is greate a List type property in ur model and in view

```
@model List<MVCSAMPLE.Models.MyModel> 
@foreach (var item in Model.PropertyWhithListType)
{
    <tr>
        <td>@item.EntityName</td>
        <td>@item.EntityDescription</td>
        <td>@item.EntityTypeName</td>
        <td>@item.IndustryName</td>
        <td>@item.Name</td>
    </tr>
}
```

Comment: I m getting this error The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[<>f__AnonymousType3`5[System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String]]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[MVCSAMPLE.Models.Entities]'.

Comment: ok then try to List<UrEntity> model = q.ToList<UrEntity>(); =))

Comment: i m getting error "cannot convert from 'System.Linq.IQueryable<AnonymousType#1>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<MCVSAMPLE.Models.Entities>'
"

Comment: or may by ur linq can return IList of Entity. the idea is that the types of ur model in controller and in view must be same. in most situations try to avoid using ViewBag or ViewData.I think its just for simple types

Comment: try to replace  select new { m.EntityName,m.EntityDescription,o.EntityTypeName };   on--- > select m

Comment: in item i m getting { EntityName = entity1, EntityDescription = Entity Description 123, EntityTypeName = Education} and still getting error 'object' does not contain a definition for 'EntityName'

Comment: if i use select m i m only able to get the values form one table but not able to get the value of table joined.

Comment: i think u have problem with type casting because u try to select AnonymousType -> select new { m.EntityName,m.EntityDescription,o.EntityTypeName }

Comment: what abt the values from another table which are joined

Comment: here is many examples for linq http://stackoverflow.com/questions/534690/linq-to-sql-return-anonymous-type

Comment: if i am using @res=>{0}, I am getting this result
{ EntityName = entity1, EntityDescription = kl, EntityTypeName = Education}{0} wht should i use so tht i m able to display "entity1" only