# LINQ Where clause with Contains where the list has complex object

Tags: c#, linq

I've seen plenty of examples of LINQ with a contains on a simple list of objects:

```
var intList= new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3 };
var result = db.TableRecords.Where(c => intList.Contains(c.RecordId)).ToList();
```

What I'm trying to do seems slightly more complicated (I think). I have a line of code similar to this one gets me the list I need:

```
var xzList = db.Relations.Where(r => someOtherList.Contains(r.zId))
                         .Select(r => new { AId = r.xId, BId = r.zId })
                         .ToList();
```

And now I want to get the result similar to the previous example but the list now has an anonymous type in it with two ints.  So how would I now get `result` where `RecordId` in `TableRecords` equals the `AId` in the anonymous type for each anonymous type in `xzList`?

Comment: var intList = xzList.Select(listObject => listObject.AId).ToList();

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Sounds like you are unsure how to get the values out of your anonymous type.  You can use GunnerL3510's solution to dump it to a list, or you should be able to inline it like this:

```
var result = 
    db.TableRecords
        .Where(c => xzList.Select(n => n.AId)
            .Contains(c.RecordId))
        .ToList();
```

Since you are naming the values in your anonymous type, you refer to them just like properties.

If you prefer to do a more structured approach, you can use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/534794/947171) method.

Comment: I was about to write `c => xzList.Any(n => n.AId == c.RecordId)` but it's more or less the same. If you want to first dump all `AId` to a separate collection (which might be faster, "GunnerL3510's solution"), consider using a `HashSet<int>`, like: `new HashSet<int>(xzList.Select(n => n.AId))`.

Comment: Okay, so it looks like I need to dump the contents of the list with anon objects into a list of just ints, then do the contains on the new list.  I guess I was thinking there would be another way to refer to the List<T>.Contains() but it starting not to look that way.

Comment: @SailingJudo No, that's not the only possibility. You Can ude the lambda arrow of my first comment if you prefer.

Comment: @SailingJudo: If the `db` object is some sort of SQL `DataContext`, you don't want to call `.ToList()` on `xzlist` unless you have an as of yet unstated reason for doing so. If you did, you'd be making two relatively expensive db calls instead of one.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
db.TableRecords.Select(c=>c.RecordId).Intercept(xzList.Select(n => n.AId)).Any()
```