# linq join return type

Tags: c#, linq

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [LINQ to SQL: Return anonymous type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/534690/linq-to-sql-return-anonymous-type)

What return type do I use for a List<> on a linq join?  I'm joining multiple tables below, I'm getting the error `'Cannot implicitly convert type System.Collections.Generic.List<AnonymousType#1> to System.Collections.Generic.List<CargoTanksDAL.aspnet_Users>`

```
    public List<> GetAspnetUsersWithMembershipAndCompany()
    {

        using (DevCargoEntities db = new DevCargoEntities())
        {
            var users = from u in db.aspnet_Users
                        join mem in db.aspnet_Membership on u.UserId equals mem.UserId
                        join cl in db.CT_CompanyLogIn on u.UserName equals cl.UserLogIn
                        join companies in db.CT_Companies on cl.CompanyID equals companies.CompanyID
                        select new
                        {
                            u.UserId,
                            u.UserName,
                            mem.Email,
                            mem.IsLockedOut,
                            mem.IsApproved,
                            mem.CreateDate,
                            companies.CompanyName
                        };

            return users.ToList();
        }
    }
```

Comment: See the top related question to this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/534690/linq-to-sql-return-anonymous-type?rq=1

Comment: What do you want to return?  You should construct your Linq query to return what you want your method to return.  If you already have some kind of User class you could use that. `select new User() { UserId = u.UserId, UserName = u.UserName ... }`

Comment: You're creating an anonymous type in the query. If you define your own type for the query, you can return a list of those.

Comment: Create a class with the desired properties and return a `List<ThatClass>`.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, that link helped.  Now would I put that new class in the data access layer or the business logic layer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would have made a new class.. for this user..

```
public class SomeKindOfUser
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public bool IsLockedOut { get; set; }
    public bool IsApproved { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
}
```

Now you can use

```
public List<SomeKindOfUser> GetAspnetUsersWithMembershipAndCompany()
```

Then in the select :

```
select new SomeKindOfUser
{
    UserId = u.UserId,
    UserName = u.UserName,
    Email = mem.Email,
    IsLockedOut = mem.IsLockedOut,
    IsApproved = mem.IsApproved,
    CreateDate = mem.CreateDate,
    CompanyName = companies.CompanyName
};
```

Comment: Where would you put the new class?  Data access layer or business logic layer?

Comment: @user1220099 as stated before "Depends on what exact purpose your function serves". But i would also add it to the business logic layer.

Answer (score 5):

None. The join does not matter here, the select does, and you select an anonymous type. You can't return an anonymous type. Better create a new class that contains the properties you want to return and instanciate that type.

You could theoretically return dynamic or object, but that is a path you really really don't want to walk. Trust me on that.

Comment: so would I put that new class in my data access layer, or my business logic layer?

Comment: Depends on what exact purpose your function serves. I'd add it to the business logic layer.