# How to filter stored procedure result using linq

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I am having one stored procedure with the following definition:

**Usp_totallisttype**

```
select table1.name,table1.Id,table2.address,table1.type
from table1
inner join table2 on table1.Id = table2.Id
where (table1.type = 'A' OR table1.type = 'B')
order by table1.Id
```

**CS :**

```
public static List<classname> Getlist()
{
    using (var Context = new DataContext())
    {

        var typelist = (from m in Context.Usp_totallisttype() 
        select new classname 
        {
         name = m.name,
         Id= m.Id,
         address = m.address,
         type = m.type
         }).ToList();
        if (typelist.Count > 0)
        {
            return typelist;
        }
        else
            return null;

    }
}
```

**Here I am calling List() method :**

```
  List<classname> typeList = classname.List();
  if (typeList != null)
  {
    var aList = typeList.where(p => p.type = "A").ToList();
    //perform some opration and assign datasorce
    var bList = typeList.where(p => p.type = "B").ToList();
    //perform some opration and assign datasorce
  }
```

**Problem :**

How can I do this:

```
var aList = typeList.where(p => p.type = "A").ToList();//How i can do this ?
//perform some opration and assign datasorce
var bList = typeList.where(p => p.type = "B").ToList();//How i can do this ? 
//perform some opration and assign data source
```

I am new in linq so please let me know in the above code have something missing or how I can make it more optimized.

Comment: What's the problem?  Also, surely you mean `p.type == "B"`.

Comment: It's not the point here, but you are also adding a list to another list (`objList.Add(typelist);`).

Comment: I think you have a problem in that the list is of object, so you're going to have a hard time reading the type property returned from your query. I'd rework the declaration of typelist  so that you don't just 'select m', but 'select new MyType {propA = m.A, probB = m.B} etc. Then you can have a list of MyType and can access it's type property in the lambda.

Comment: @user2025312 is right. You can find a solution to your question here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/534794/1012409

Comment: @redeemer please tell me what is best way to handle IQueryable return type ?

Comment: @user2025312 i had changed the code please check update

Comment: @Sunny, I'm not sure I've understood your question properly. Did you mean that you want to find out what is T in IQueryable<T> ? You can use IQueryable.ElementType property to get Type provided .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im not clear about how are you going to get "type" property from object p directly. First you should define data struct equal to SQL query result struct.

```
struct DBRecord
{
public string id
public string name {get;set;}
public string address {get;set;}
public string type {get;set;}
}


//Selection:

List<DBRecord> aList = typeList.FindAll(p => ((DBRecord)p).type == "A");

List<DBRecord> bList = typeList.FindAll(p => ((DBRecord)p).type == "B");
```

Comment: Thanks this is the cast which i was missing. Thanks a lot :-)