# How to join two tables in linq and not get anonymous type result set

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

I would like to get a result set from both PriceAssocationLookup and PriceAssociation tables.  How do I do this and not get an error due to Anonymous Type?
Here is my code:

```
IEnumerable<IPriceAssociationLookupRepository> IPriceAssociationLookupRepository.GetPacs(string upc)
{
    using (PortalDataEntities entities = new PortalDataEntities())
    {
        var priceAssociationLookups = (from priceassociationlookup in entities.PriceAssociationLookups
                                       join priceassociation in entities.PriceAssociations on priceassociationlookup.PriceAssociationCode equals priceassociation.PriceAssociationCode
                                       where priceassociationlookup.Upc == upc
                                       select priceassociationlookup ).ToList();

        return priceAssociationLookups;
    }

}
```

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/534794/2420979

Comment: @DavidHaney - yes, this worked. How do I select your response as the answer?  I had to rework my code a bit, but the general premise you suggested worked.

Comment: Just post an answer yourself including the link, then accept it. :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [LINQ to SQL: Return anonymous type?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/534690/linq-to-sql-return-anonymous-type)

Comment: Marking as duplicate is the most appropriate action here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a **ViewModel** and add **properties** for the columns you want to return and return **List** of the view model type, here is my code, the way i used to do :

```
List<PreviousTest> Result = (from d in db.dc_tpatient_bookingd

                            join og in db.dc_tp_organization 
                            on d.clientid equals og.OrgId into a

                            from og in a.DefaultIfEmpty()

                            from t in db.dc_tp_test

                            from p in db.dc_tp_tprocess

                            where d.bookingid == BookingID

                            && t.TestId == d.testid

                            && d.ProcessID == p.processid

                            && d.bookingdid != BookingDID

                            select new PreviousTest
                            {
                             BookingID = d.bookingid,
                             BookingDId = d.bookingdid,
                             TestID = t.TestId,
                             TestName = t.Test_Name,
                             ProcessName = p.name,
                             ProcessID = p.processid,
                             ClientID =  d.clientid
                             }).ToList();
```

Here is my viewmodel :

```
public class PreviousTest
    {

        public long BookingID { get; set; }
        public long BookingDId { get; set; }
        public long TestID { get; set; }
        public string TestName { get; set; }
        public long ProcessID { get; set; }
        public string ProcessName { get; set; }
        public string ClientID { get; set; }

    }
```