# How to use linq Sum in a dynamic object

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, code-first

In Data Access Layer I have de following query:

```cs
var result = from income in context.Incomes
                join order in context.Orders on income.OrderId equals order.OrderId
                select new
                {
                    Voucher = order.VoucherSeries + "-" + order.VoucherNumber,
                    Amount = income.IncomeAmount
                };
return result.ToList();
```

In Business layer how to use linq Sum for sum Amount?

Comment: `result.Sum(x=>x.Amount)` ?

Comment: Do you mean IncomeAmount or is there another field called Amount in either the income or order classes?

Comment: How on earth did you declare the method that contained this code in any meaningful manner?

Comment: @L.B Hi, I want to Sum in other layer (Business).

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Presumably it returns `List<object>`, which is to say that he didn't, in that it's not *meaningful*, even though it compiles.

Comment: Which was *kinda* my point, although I'm not entirely sure that is correct either since `List<T>` allows for additions, so I'm pretty sure it has to return `IEnumerable<object>`, which begs the question; *why*.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Oh, right, it would need to be `IEnumerable<object>`, not `List<object>`.

Comment: Or, `IEnumerable<dynamic>` which in my opinion is a lot worse, because you've then *designed* something that *doesn't have to be* loosely typed and runtime-based discovery and evaulation.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen If he was doing that then he likely wouldn't have needed to ask this question.

Comment: I don't presume to know why anyone asks questions, I only try to answer their actual questions or help them arrive at the best question to ask. In this case I'm not sure which approach to try. In my opinion, @Servy has the only correct answer here, don't return anonymous objects.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Return anonymous type?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/534690/return-anonymous-type)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anonymous objects are specifically designed to be used just within the scope in which they are created.  If you want to be able to access this data outside of the current scope then you should be creating a new named type that has the two relevant properties that you need, rather than using an anonymous type.

Comment: I agree with You that using named class seems to be the most suitable solution, so I removed my answer to avoid confusion.