# Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<AnonymousType#1>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Model.tblLaborBankAccount>'

Tags: c#, linq, generics

I have a problem in returning a list, 
here is my code:

```
    public List<tblLaborBankAccount> ListAllLaborBankAccountByLaborID (int laborID)
    {
        var result = (from b in context.tblBankNames
                      join c in context.tblLaborBankAccounts
                      on b.bknBankNameID equals c.bknBankNameID
                      where c.lbrLaborID == laborID
                      select (new { c, b })
                              ).ToList();

        return result;
    }
```

and the `result` returns an anonymous type, because I'm returning a join query and the return type is not `tblLaborBankAccount` anymore.

should I create a new class for this anonymous type or there's a better way?

Thanks.

Comment: What is `tblLaborBankAccount`? You can create instance of it and return the list?

Comment: .. or looks like you can simply `select c` and return the list. But what's the point joining with `tblBankNames` then?

Comment: You are currently returning data from both tables. Do you *want* data from both tables and if so how do you expect to put it into a list of only one type?

Comment: I don't expect so. I just wondering if there is a easier way to do so instead of creating a new class?

Comment: The solution really depends on information you need to return. So your comment in a deleted answer is important : "*I want to return something like this : `select (new { c.accNumber, b.bknName })`*"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The select statement is a projection which creates an anonymous class.

Anonymous classes can be used within a method, but cannot be returned as a result.

You could return a `List<Tuple<tblBankName, tblLaborBankAccount>>` like this:

```
public List<Tuple<tblBankName, tblLaborBankAccount>> ListAllLaborBankAccountByLaborID (int laborID)
{
    var result = (from b in context.tblBankNames
                  join c in context.tblLaborBankAccounts
                  on b.bknBankNameID equals c.bknBankNameID
                  where c.lbrLaborID == laborID
                  select (new Tuple<tblBankName, tblLaborBankAccount>( c, b ))
                          ).ToList();

    return result;
}
```

Or you could declare a struct / class to contain your results:

```
public class BankAccountDetails
{
     public tblBankName BankName {get;set;}
     public tblLaborBankAccount BankAccount {get;set;}
}
```

And then return a list of them:

```
public List<BankAccountDetails> ListAllLaborBankAccountByLaborID (int laborID)
{
    var result = (from b in context.tblBankNames
                  join c in context.tblLaborBankAccounts
                  on b.bknBankNameID equals c.bknBankNameID
                  where c.lbrLaborID == laborID
                  select (new BankAccountDetails{ BankName =  c, BankAccount =  b })
                          ).ToList();

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Returning your own class would probably be the easiest solution and makes clear, what is returned from your method.
See also: [Return anonymous type results?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/534690/return-anonymous-type)