# How to create an anonymous type list from derived classes - EF Code First

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, ef-code-first, anonymous-types

I have the following classes:

**Base Class:** `Like` has `IsRead`, `WhoLikedId`, `WhoseLikedId` properties.

**Derived Classes:** `PostLike` has an additional `PostId` property, `CommentLike` has an additional `CommentId` property, `ReplyLike` has an additional `ReplyId` property.

Based on `likes`, I want to generate a notification list. I can do this separately per each derived class like this:

```
  var postlikes = db.Likes
                    .OfType<PostLike>
                    .Select(pl => new 
                         {
                            NotificationText = 'Someone liked your post.',
                            Type = "PostLike",
                            RelatedItem = pl.PostId
                         });

  var commentlikes = db.Likes
                    .OfType<CommentLike>
                    .Select(cl => new 
                         {
                            NotificationText = 'Someone liked your comment.',
                            Type = "CommentLike",
                            RelatedItem = cl.CommentId
                         });
  //the same for replylikes
```

I wonder if there is a way to generate such a list by using **ONE LINQ** statement?

If not, do you think the way I handle `Likes` is a good practice?

Comment: not that it's critical, assuming it's a typo here and accurate in your code, but you have a syntax error with the closing curly brace on your selects missing the closing paren.

Comment: also, are you basically asking if there is a way to assign to multiple objects/vars with a single LINQ statement?

Comment: @Daved I fixed the coding error. Since they inherited from the same class, I wonder if I can do this with single LinQ statement instead of three.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this on anonymous types: [Return anonymous type results?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/534690/return-anonymous-type)

The nutshell version is you might be able to, but don't.

Your best bet it to use a view model, say a `NotificationsViewModel` which has the fields you need, and returning that from the queries.

```
  var likes = db.Likes
                .Take(10)
                .ToList()
                .Select(like => new NotificationsViewModel
                 {
                    Text = resolveNotificationString(like.GetType().Name),
                    Type = like.GetType().Name,
                    RelatedItem = like.Id
                 });
```

This makes the following assumptions and a couple of implicit changes to your model / use case,

- This is for populating a view,
- Assumes that you only want the top few, since it is for a view. You could filter (`Where()`) ones that are unread, the newest ones, or whatever fits your application.
- You have a mechanism *somewhere* to get a `string` for the `Text`, based upon the type name of the like.
- The `Like` base class having a common ID, instead of `PostId`, CommentId`, etc.

Comment: I considered `RelatedItem`  be either `PostId` or `CommentId` or `ReplyId`. This way, when a user clicks on a notification item, they can display the related post or comment or reply. I guess this is not possible? With your approach, when user clicks on a notification, I will get the related item from the db and know whether it is a comment or sth else by using `LikeId`, is that right?

Comment: If you have the ID, there is no reason you can't return the Post, Comment, or Reply on click based on type. You will know whether it's a comment or something else based on ID + type name. Using both prevents conflict if you have a ReplyID and CommentID of the same value, since they are separate types.

Comment: I cannot use `.GetType().Name` in a linq statement as well.

Comment: @erkaner That's not true, but you can't use it in the part of this query that gets sent to the database. That's why I called `ToList()` - it forces evaluation.