# How to return a join statement in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, join

I want to return result 3 to the main method

```
 var result = (from od in orders
        join em in employees on od.EmployeeID equals em.EmployeeID
        join ct in customers on od.CustomerID equals ct.CustomerID
        //orderby em.EmployeeID
        select new
        {
            od.OrderID,
            od.ShipCountry,
            ct.CompanyName,
            ct.ContactName,
            FullName = em.FirstName + ' '+ em.LastName, 
        });


 var newOrders = result.OrderBy("OrderID DESC");

 var result3 = newOrders
    .ToList()
    .Skip(rowsPerPage * (page-1))
    .Take(rowsPerPage);

 return result3;
}

 public class MyJoin {
 public int OrderID { get; set; }
 public DateTime OrderDate { get; set; }
 public string ShipCountry { get; set; }
 public string CompanyName { get; set; }
 public string ContactName { get; set; }
 public string EmployeeName { get; set; }
 }
```

I'm not sure how to return it as a simple

```
return result3;
```

Does not do the trick, I get an error

> Cannot implicitly convert type
>   `System.Collections.Generic.List<AnonymousType#1>` to
>   `System.Collections.Generic.List<UserQuery.MyJoin>`

Comment: Is `result.OrderBy("OrderID DESC");` valid? What the signature of this method? Dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/534690/return-anonymous-type-results.

Comment: You need to show your class UserQuery.MyJoin

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not working because in here:

```
select new
{
    od.OrderID,
    od.ShipCountry,
    ct.CompanyName,
    ct.ContactName,
    FullName = em.FirstName + ' '+ em.LastName, 
}
```

You are creating new type -> AnonymouseType, and it is not `MyJoin` type which you are expecting to be returned in your function. Simply use:

```
select new UserQuery.MyJoin
{
   OrderID = od.OrderID,
   ...
}
```

of course you need to fill fields from `MyJoin` class.

Comment: I have edited my post so now it shows the MyJoin class I created . Can you please show me how to use this class to return `result 3`

Comment: @user3521029 fill it like it's in my answer, do it for all fields you need. It will work just like in your question, but put property name on the right hand of value.

Comment: i think you still need to convert it to List like`return result3.ToList();`

Comment: @WaqarAhmed yeah, probably yes. But I think OP does not need to return List of elements, `IEnumerable` should be fine :)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot return an anonymous type from a function call.

You will have to explicitly define the type you expect anyhow, then

```
var result = (from od in orders
    join em in employees on od.EmployeeID equals em.EmployeeID
    join ct in customers on od.CustomerID equals ct.CustomerID
    //orderby em.EmployeeID
    select new UserQuery.MyJoin
    {
        od.OrderID,
        od.ShipCountry,
        ct.CompanyName,
        ct.ContactName,
        FullName = em.FirstName + ' '+ em.LastName, 
    });


var newOrders = result.OrderBy("OrderID DESC");

var result3 = newOrders
.Skip(rowsPerPage * (page-1))
.Take(rowsPerPage);
.ToList()

return result3;
```

Note that you do not need to materialize the result (no .ToList() needed) if this is Linq to Objects, or if the DbContext is available to the caller.

Comment: I have edited my post so now it shows the MyJoin class I created . Can you please show me how to use this class to return result 3 .

Comment: Updated using your entire example.  Note that I put .ToList() last.  It is far less efficient to create a list *then* skip records.

Comment: now I'm getting the following error `Invalid initializer member declarator`. I think it's not initializing MyJoin properly?

Answer (score 0):

Specify the type -

In your case

```
IQueryable<UserQuery.MyJoin> result = (from od in orders
    join em in employees on od.EmployeeID equals em.EmployeeID
    join ct in customers on od.CustomerID equals ct.CustomerID
    //orderby em.EmployeeID
    select new UserQuery.MyJoin
    {
        od.OrderID,
        od.ShipCountry,
        ct.CompanyName,
        ct.ContactName,
        FullName = em.FirstName + ' '+ em.LastName, 
    });
```

Comment: I get the following error `Cannot initialize type 'UserQuery.MyJoin' with a collection initializer because it does not implement 'System.Collections.IEnumerable'`