# LINQ return type and use in the other function

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to get a result from LINQ query and pass it to different function to use there.

This is my first function that called from browser. Then, `GetAddressByIncID`is called.

```
 // GET: Hello/5
public void GetModel(int? incID)
    {
        var incAddress = GetAddressByIncID(incID);
        var siteID = GetSiteIDbyAddress(incAddress);
        LoadSite(siteID);
    }

private ?returntype? GetAddressByIncID(int? incID)
    {
        var incAddress = (from address in db.Incs
                    where address.IncID == incID
                    select new
                    {
                        IncID = address.IncID,
                        Number = address.Number,
                        Direction = address.Direction,
                        StreetName = address.StreetName,
                        Zip = address.Zip,
                        City = city.CityDesc,
                        State = state.StateDesc
                    }).FirstOrDefault();
        return incAddress;
    }
```

At this point, I could get a query result that I wanted. I only needed one or null so I set `FirstOrDefault()`.
Within this function, I am able to access values inside of incAddress, like incAddress.IncID, and I want to do this in other function when it passed to them. Because its type is Anonymous Type, I am not sure what return type should I use.

Once this is returned, I pass it to other function that called `GetSiteIDbyAddress` to find out `SiteID`. This result may be multiple.

```
    private ?returntype? GetSiteIDbyAddress(string incAddress)
        {    
          var searchaddress = (from address in db.Addresses
                                     where PrimaryAddressNumber == incAddress.Number && Direction == incAddress.Direction && StreetName == incAddress.StreetName
                                     select new
                                     {
                                         SiteID = address.SiteID
                                     });

            return searchaddress;
        }
```

Would you please give me a suggestion on both first and second function's return type? I searched and tried (list, array, etc) but could not find a great solution for it.

**EDIT:**

With suggestions, I have edited my code to looks below. Now I am able to use values from `IncAddress` to pass to the other function. However, the other problem arise.

```
public class IncAddress
    {
        public int IncID { get; set; }
        public string Number { get; set; }
        .
        .
    }
public class IncSite
{
    public int? SiteID { get; set; }
    .
    .
}

private IncAddress GetAddressByIncID(int incID)
    {
        var incAddress = (from address in db.Incs
                    where address.IncID == incID
                    select new IncAddress
                    {
                        IncID = address.IncID,
                        Number = address.Number,
                        Direction = address.Direction,
                        StreetName = address.StreetName,
                        Zip = address.Zip,
                        City = city.CityDesc,
                        State = state.StateDesc
                    }).FirstOrDefault();
        return incAddress;
    }

private IncSite GetSiteIDbyAddress(IncidentAddress incidentAddress)
    {    
      var searchaddress = (from address in db.Addresses
                                 where PrimaryAddressNumber == incAddress.Number
                                 select new IncSite
                                 {
                                     SiteID = address.SiteID
                                 });
        return searchaddress;
    }
```

On `GetSiteIDbyAddress`, I get an error says:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable <
>   HelloWorld.Controllers.HelloController.IncSite > ' to
>   'HelloWorld.Controllers.HelloController.IncSite'. An explicit
>   conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

I think it is because I did not put `FirstOrDefault()` because I expect multiple record will be found by this query. How can I complete this function to get a multiple results?

Comment: Create a class to hold the data.  In your LINQ statement, use `new myClass` instead of `new`, and you can return the type of `myClass`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Return anonymous type results?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/534690/return-anonymous-type-results)

Comment: Obviously its not a good practice to pass around an anonymous type. So if you need to use the resultant set outside of the query or method/function you should do as 'un-lucky' said in his answer and create a class. Personally dislike using `var` I like to declare things for what they are.

Comment: Thank you Tim. I tried to use Class before and did not turn out well. But I now realized I forgot to add  -- select new 'myClass'. It works now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in two ways, **either** by creating a new class Let it be some `Address` with those selected values as fields and in this case return type will respect to `Address`(Address if you use FirstOrDefault, List if you use `.ToList()` and so on). **Or** you can specify the return type as `dynamic` in this case no other changes is needed. But I suggest you to create a Class if possible and avoid the usage of `dynamic` in this case, since

> it is a lot slower and won't have the same compile time error checks
>   as a proper class

updates as per David's comment

**Case 1 :**

```
//definition should be something like this
public class Address
{
    public string IncID { get; set; }
    public string Number { get; set; }
    public string Direction { get; set; }
    public string StreetName { get; set; }
    public string Zip { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
}
```

And the Method should be like this:

```
private Address GetAddressByIncID(int? incID)
{
    var incAddress = (from address in db.Incs
                where address.IncID == incID
                select new Address
                {
                    IncID = address.IncID,
                    Number = address.Number,
                    Direction = address.Direction,
                    StreetName = address.StreetName,
                    Zip = address.Zip,
                    City = city.CityDesc,
                    State = state.StateDesc
                }).FirstOrDefault();
    return incAddress;
}
```

**Case 2**

```
private dynamic GetAddressByIncID(int? incID)
{
     var incAddress = // Query here

     return incAddress;
}
```

Comment: It should be noted that dynamic is a lot slower and won't have the same compile time error checks as a proper class

Comment: @DavidS.: Thank you for the valued inf. I have quoted them in the updated answer

Comment: Thank you so much un-lucky. I modified my code with your suggestion. However, I encounter another problem. I edited my original post and please give me an advice how to get multiple query results.