# linq syntax: What is the type that this returns? How can I now go ahead and use firstRow.ingredientName etc?

Tags: c#, linq

The following is my linq expression:

```
return from c in db.RecipeIngredients
       join d in db.Ingredients on c.IngredientID equals d.IngredientsID
       where c.RecipeID.Equals(recipeID)
       select (d.IngredientsID,c.Unit,c.IngredientID,c.Amount).ToList();
```

This should be returning a list of rows of ingredient information. What is the type that this returns? How can I now go ahead and use firstRow.ingredientName etc?

Comment: Does that compile?  Take a look at the following post for some ideas: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/534690/return-anonymous-type-results

Comment: You should read [ask] and take the [tour]; 6 posts with all but one with a score of 0 or less will limit your participation soon.

Answer (score 4):

First, I think your code will not compile, you're missing two parentheses:

```
return (from c in db.RecipeIngredients
   join d in db.Ingredients on c.IngredientID equals d.IngredientsID
   where c.RecipeID.Equals(recipeID)
   select (d.IngredientsID,c.Unit,c.IngredientID,c.Amount)).ToList();
```

Ok, next, `(d.IngredientsID,c.Unit,c.IngredientID,c.Amount)` if you're on C# 7.0 that's a declarative tuple with all the variables, so you need to return that types between parentheses, like here (I will assume the types of your vars, correct it as needed):

```
public List<(int, UnitNames, int, double)> GetRecipe(int recipeId)
{
    return (from c in db.RecipeIngredients
       join d in db.Ingredients on c.IngredientID equals d.IngredientsID
       where c.RecipeID.Equals(recipeID)
       select (d.IngredientsID,c.Unit,c.IngredientID,c.Amount)).ToList();

}
```

To access the variables you acces like this:

```
var recipe = GetRecipe(recipeId);

foreach(var ingredient in recipe)
{
    var ingredientsId = ingredient.Item1;
    var unit = ingredient.Item2;
    var ingredientId = ingredient.Item3;
    var amount = ingredient.Item4;
}
```

In any case, I would recommend to create a class to pass the data, it will result in a much clear code:

```
public class Ingredient
{
    public int IngredientsId { get; set; }
    public UnitNames Unit { get; set; }
    public int IngredientId { get; set; }
    public double Amount { get; set; }
}

public List<Ingredient> GetRecipe(int recipeId)
{
    return (from c in db.RecipeIngredients
       join d in db.Ingredients on c.IngredientID equals d.IngredientsID
       where c.RecipeID.Equals(recipeID)
       select new Ingredient { 
                                 IngredientsId = d.IngredientsID, 
                                 Unit = c.Unit,
                                 IngredientId = c.IngredientID, 
                                 Amount = c.Amount 
                             }).ToList();

}
```