# anonymous type to populate listview

Tags: sqlite, listview, xamarin, join, anonymous-types

I am joining four tables using linq which is returning anonymous type, what is the best way to return result from multiple tables using this linq query? and How to populate listview with anonymous type object?

```
       var Hofid=2
      var query = from HOF in conn.Table<hof>()
                    join UC in conn.Table<uc>() on HOF.UCID equals  UC.UCID
                    join CITY in conn.Table<city>() on UC.CITYID equals  CITY.CITYID
                    join  Dis in conn.Table<district>() on CITY.DISTTID equals  Dis.DISTTID                        
                   where HOF.HOFID == Hofid 
                  . select new
                    { CNICNO = HOF.HOFID, HOFNAME = HOF.Name,DISTRICT = Dis.Dist_Name,UC = UC.UC_Name, CITY = CITY.city_Name}
```

Comment: Anonymous types can be difficult to deal with. Any reason you can't create an object for what you're selecting, something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/534794/8395242)?

Comment: I tried it this way but i am getting [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52051852/sqlite-join-queries-in-xamarin-android-and-showing-record-in-gridview).