# Return anonymous type results when using linq

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, entity-framework-6

I have method GetOrders which returns anonymous type results which i am using to bind data grid. Data Grid is for just reading purpose.

Here is the method which returns anonymous type results.

```
public IEnumerable GetOrders()
{
   var q=(from pd in dataContext.tblProducts 
   join od in dataContext.tblOrders on pd.ProductID equals od.ProductID 
   orderby od.OrderID 
   select new { 
     od.OrderID,
     pd.ProductID,
     pd.Name,
     pd.UnitPrice,
     od.Quantity,
    od.Price,
             }).ToList(); 
}
```

So far, it works fine but i don't know if this is a right way to return anonymous type results from a method?

Comment: Why not create a strongly type object model? Any particular reason to use anonymous type?

Comment: I wouldn't use anonynous types for a public api - even if you own it!

Comment: better way would be define properties as well `select new {OrderId=od.OrderID,ProductId=pd.ProductID,Name=pd.Name,UnitPrice=pd.UnitPrice,Quantity=od.Quantity,Price=od.Price}`

Comment: IEnumerable already returns properties.

Comment: it's better to be somewhat explicit here

Comment: If you intend to edit the records you can't use anonymous objects as their properties are read-only and if you don't intend to edit, you should use a `ListView` with a `GridView` instead of a `DataGrid`.

Comment: @Aarif The code above already returns an anonymous type with those properties. You don't need to specify a name unless you want to change it.

Comment: Since you're returning a List<t> anyhow, I don't follow why the signature is not List<object>. If ALL you're doing is binding to that ienumerable as read only then you're not going to set the properties to anything else then type safety seems rather academic. So long as you (or someone else) don't later forget and re-use that method. Defining a specific class is an investment ameliorates that later risk.

Comment: I have tried changing signatures to object and it also works fine but i had to case it to IEnumerable when results to data grid.With List(Of Objects) i get error message list of anonymous type cannot be converted to List(Of Objects). Could you IEnumerable(of Objects)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Return anonymous type results?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/534690/return-anonymous-type-results)

Answer (score 4):

It probably works because the other side uses reflection to determine the structure, but the general rule of thumb is that you shouldn't use anonymous types across the boundaries of your method.

Instead, you should make proper classes to return the results.

Comment: Thanks. What are the draw backs of using anonymous types?

Comment: Losing type safety for example, as you experience now. You could just have made the return type `object`... The return type isn't useful at all now.

Comment: I would have to cast object to IEnumerable when binding reults to data grid.

Comment: Still, it doesn't say anything. You could for that purpose return a `string`, which implements `IEnumerable` too... Got the point?