# How can we get list of two column say firstname and lastname from customer table in mvc using linq query

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

[Customer Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QyYLP.png)

Every time I run this I get an error:

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List1[<>f__AnonymousType1 2[System.String,System.String]]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable1[CRUD__MVC.Models.Customer]

Code:

```
public ActionResult FirstLastName()
{
    return View(Name()); 
}

IEnumerable<Customer>Name()   
{
    using (AdventureWorksLTDataContext db = new AdventureWorksLTDataContext())
    {
        return (IEnumerable<Customer>)db.Customers.Select(c => new { FirstName = c.FirstName, LastName = c.LastName }).ToList();
    }
}
```

Comment: Because Anonymous type is not Customer.

Comment: Assuming you have a `Customer` model: `return (IEnumerable<Customer>)db.Customers.Select(c => new Customer{ FirstName = c.FirstName, LastName = c.LastName }).ToList();`

Comment: How Can I rewrite the code. I am new to coding sorry

Comment: @RahulSharma, `Select()` returns `IEnumerable<T>` already. Converting sequence of `Select()` into `.ToList()` and again to `IEnumerable<T>` is just over engineering. I believe.

Comment: The customer table consist of multiple columns(I want to fetch list of all firstname and lastname column )   I am using linq to sql to create the datacontext class..     Tried   return db.Customers.Select(c => new Customer { FirstName = c.FirstName, LastName = c.LastName })

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a new `Model` class which will consist of your selected data from the `Customer` class:

```
public class GetCustomerInformation
{
 public string FirstName {get;set;}
 public string LastName {get;set;}
}
```

And you can then `Select` the required like this:

```
IEnumerable<GetCustomerInformation>Name()   
{
    using (AdventureWorksLTDataContext db = new AdventureWorksLTDataContext())
    {
        return (IEnumerable<GetCustomerInformation>)db.Customers.Select(c => new GetCustomerInformation { FirstName = c.FirstName, LastName = c.LastName });
    }
}
```

I have made a sample here for you reference. I am manually adding data to the list and then selecting what is required: https://dotnetfiddle.net/CW9APV

Now since you are querying the DB to get your data, you can't create entities as part of a query. Entities can be created outside of queries and inserted into the data store using a `DataContext`. You can then retrieve them using queries.

So a workaround would be:

Generate a class that derives from your LINQ to SQL class:

```
internal class CustomerView: Customer { }
```

Write your query in this way:

```
IEnumerable<Customer> Name()   
{
    using (AdventureWorksLTDataContext db = new AdventureWorksLTDataContext())
    {
        var query= db.Customers.Select(c => new CustomerView { FirstName = c.FirstName, LastName = c.LastName }).ToList();
        //Cast it back to Customer
        return (query.Cast<Customer>())
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. It really helps however I wanted to ask isn't there any way apart from creating a new model class

Comment: @NewbieCoder You can take a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/534690/return-anonymous-type-results for different options regarding your case.

Comment: Hey thank you going through the code again
Actually I am getting null data in even this scenario.
. .
public ActionResult FirstLastName()
        {
            var Name = (IEnumerable<Customer>)db.Customers.Select(c => new Customer { FirstName = c.FirstName, LastName = c.LastName });

            return View(Name);
        }
.
.
.
.
Error : "Explicit construction of entity type 'CRUD__MVC.Models.Customer' in query is not allowed."