# Get Anonymous Type from Object Type

Tags: c#, anonymous-types

For the code shown below

```
using System;

public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Test t = new Test();
        object AnonymousInside= t.GetAnonymousType();
        Console.Write(AnonymousInside.Key);//Error on compilation
    }

    public object GetAnonymousType()
    {
        return new {Key="KeyName",Value="ValueName"};
    }
}
```

How can I take the anonymous type back from type `object`?

If that is not possible then how this code works?

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ConfirmPassword, new { maxlength = 35, type = "password", @class="textArea  margindrop",placeholder="Confirm password"})
```

Its [Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.inputextensions.textboxfor%28v=vs.108%29.aspx)

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10073319/returning-anonymous-type-in-c-sharp

Comment: via Reflection probably

Comment: inside TextBoxFor - used reflection

Comment: @Grundy Actually what might be the reason that anonymous types are not allowed as return types in methods. I think the type can be inferred from the return type of the method. rite?

Comment: @SubinJacob it can, but how you marked return type? for solve this was introduced keyword `dynamic` :-)

Comment: @Grundy But `dynamic` is weekly typed. Its used when the the type in unknown. Actually, anonymous type in c# is not anonymous I think because its defined while creating.

Comment: @SubinJacob anonymous type get his name only in compiling time, so you cann't reference to it in code time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not want to use `dynamic` you may try something like this

```
using System;

public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var AnonymousInside = GetAnonymousTyped(GetAnonymousObject(), new {Key="",Value=""});
        Console.Write(AnonymousInside.Key);//All Ok
    }

    public static T GetAnonymousTyped<T>(object o, T _)
    {
        return (T)o;
    }

    public static object GetAnonymousObject()
    {
         return new {Key="KeyName",Value="ValueName"};
    }
}
```

Comment: Means, I have to define the Type twice?

Comment: @SubinJacob yes, first for return, second for casting result

Answer (score 3):

You can make it dynamic

```
dynamic AnonymousInside= t.GetAnonymousType();
```

Though you should use a class,struct instead

---

If you still want to use anonymous type

It's mentioned in the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397696.aspx):

> The compiler provides a name for each anonymous type, although your
>   application cannot access it.

So,the only way to access it through object would be using `reflection` or `dynamic`

Comment: But why a dynamic type required? the anonymous type is already defined in the compile time itself. rite?

Comment: Its not necessary to use `object` type for this purpose. I just want to pass anonymous data.

Comment: @SubinJacob it's mentioned in the docs: `If you want to pass them outside the method boundary, consider using an ordinary named struct or class instead of an anonymous type.`

Comment: @SubinJacob and this would make it more clear :`The compiler provides a name for each anonymous type, although your application cannot access it. `

Comment: I don't want to use reflection or dynamic since there won't be any compile time check.  But I expected there would be one because the type is defined at compile time itself. If that was possible I could use it in scenarios where more than one type have to be returned.

Comment: See this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.inputextensions.textboxfor(v=vs.108).aspx Here, we are passing an anonymous type to this method. And C# parse it somehow and generate its HTML. My doubt comes from here.