# Return data type for an AnonymousType#1

Tags: c#, .net, types, return

What is the correct return data type for an AnonymousType#1?

This code is working.

```
var c = p.IQueryableGetAll()
         .Where(r => r.Gender == "M")
         .Select(r => new { r.FirstName, r.LastName })
         .ToList();
```

But when I placed it inside a function, error occurs.

```
public List<object> GetFirstNameAndLastNameOfMales()
{
   var p = new Program();
   return p.IQueryableGetAll()
           .Where(r => r.Gender == "M")
           .Select(r => new { r.FirstName, r.LastName })
           .ToList();
}
```

Here's the error

> Cannot implicitly convert type
>   `System.Collections.Generic.List<AnonymousType#1>` to
>   `System.Collections.Generic.List<object>`

How is it done correctly? Thank you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10073319/returning-anonymous-type-in-c-sharp

Comment: Why do you *want* to return an anonymous type? If you need to use the contents of the anonymous type for longer than the scope of a single method, just make a named class to hold the data.

Comment: I just want an instant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You query in both cases is correct. However that causes the problem in the second case is the return type of your method.

You could try this one:

```
 return p.IQueryableGetAll()
         .Where(r => r.Gender == "M")
         .Select(r => new { r.FirstName, r.LastName }).ToList<Object>();
```

The reason why you are getting this error is because

`Select(r => new { r.FirstName, r.LastName })`

select an anonymous type for each element in the sequence that has `Gender==M`. An the `.ToList()` at the end of your query creates a `List` of objects that have as their type this anonymnous type with these two properties.

A better option would be to create a class that will hold these two properties, let's call it `Customer` and then do the following:

```
public List<Customer> GetFirstNameAndLastNameOfMales()
{
    var p = new Program();
    return p.IQueryableGetAll()
            .Where(r => r.Gender == "M")
            .Select(r => new Customer { 
                    FirstName = r.FirstName, 
                    LastName = r.LastName
            }).ToList();
}
```

Comment: Works of course but it would be good to point out that returning anonymous types casted to `object` should be reconsidered twice.

Comment: why? is it a bad practice?

Comment: @KonradKokosa thanks for your comment ! That's why I have said that a better option would be to create a class that will replace the anonymous type.

Comment: @Ryan I say that's not a good practice, because you have written a method for gettting the last name and first name of all males. Since you need this information for all males, you could use an object that will hold it for each male and then make up a collection of them and return it to the caller of your method.

Comment: @Ryan How do you plan to use the object?  You can't *do* anything with it.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because `List<T>` is not covariant - it is a list of a specific type, so you can't add any object to it.  You can either:

1. Create a concrete type and use it
2. Cast your result to object :

   ```
   .Select(r => (object)(new { r.FirstName, r.LastName }))
   ```
3. change the return type to `IEnumerable<object>` which *is* covariant (since you can't add to it)

Option 1 is the cleanest but requires additional code - options 2 and 3 are easy on the query side but require reflection or `dynamic` on the client side (and run-time vulnerability, and lack of compile-time safety, etc.).

Comment: @D Stanley I would be grateful to you, if you could take a look at my post and tell me where I am wrong, since I got a downvote, without a comment pointing me out where I am wrong. Thank you very much in advance!