# Unknown C# type

Tags: c#, .net, var

I've a method `exMethod` that return the value in this way:

```
return new {name = name, surname = surname};
```

and I use this code

```
var person = exMethod();
```

but at this point how can I access to its fields? I've tried with

```
person.name
```

but  is thrown the exception

```
'object' does not contain a definition for 'name'
```

Comment: What does your method signature look like, I'm guessing its `public object exMethod(...)`. Try changing `object` to `dynamic`.

Comment: Post the full implementation of `exMethod`. You simply say `return new { stuff }`, not `return new Person(){ stuff };` so it likely doesn't know what to do with the returned value when assigned it to `person`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Returning anonymous type in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10073319/returning-anonymous-type-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 11):

Anonymous types can't be passed across the boundaries of a method without losing their type (they will revert to `object`). Since you can't cast it, you are stuck.

You have to create a type to expose that to the outside of the creating method. (I don't want to mention `dynamic` as a solution)

Comment: If you don't want to mention ****** as a solution, then why did you mention it?

Comment: Yep, but how would you understand me else? @Servy

Comment: And I don't mention it as a solution, it is just a random word in my answer.

Comment: And mentioning it makes it dramatically more likely that it'll get used than just not mentioning it at all.

Comment: Nevertheless, using an anonymous type in other classes throws an exception, because the concrete type is private.

Comment: @IllidanS4 It's not private.  It's internal, so it'll only throw if it's used in another assembly.  If only they had been made private...

Comment: why are you not happy to the use dynamic?

Comment: You don't have compile time checks on variables any more. If it fails, it fails when the code runs. (That is, when 100 customers are using it already and you can't pull it back any more)

Comment: @davidinho it allows a call to anything at compile time even if the properties don't exist on an object they can be called. These problems then come up at runtime which isn't good.

Comment: @PatrickHofman Can't the same be said for all Python code in existence?

Comment: I am not familiar with Python, but I am sure compile-time checks is a pro for C#. Can't imagine not to have it.

Answer (score 1):

you could do

```
dynamic person = exMethod();
```

but not recommended and is 'the easy way out' and you wouldn't have any compile time errors then. Another solution could be to use reflection but that can be heavy.

The best (safest, best practice) idea is probably to create a class to define the type that is being returned

```
class Foo {
    public string name {get;set;}
    public string surname{get;set;}
}

return new Foo(){ name = name, surname = surname }
```

then you would be able to use those properties

Answer (score 0):

<strike>If you have control over `exMethod`, modify it as [Patrick suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33019364/3887516).</strike>

If you don't and *must* accept it as an `Object` use `dynamic` instead of `var`:

```
dynamic person = exMethod();
person.name;
```

Answer is worthless, comments are good, particularly @Servy's:

> Anonymous classes are internal, so if it's in an API that you don't have access to then `dynamic` wouldn't work. It's only an option when you have control over the implementation of the method.

Comment: Don't use `dynamic` unless you really really have to.

Comment: @PatrickHofman I decided it is worth mentioning (even though you don't want to mention it). I do agree there has to be a good justification for this. If there is such justification, this solution is not only correct, it's ***required***. `dynamic` is there to be used (when needed).

Comment: I hope whoever downvoted is happy. this is useful for some cases, and downvoting just because there might be other solutions is "*not smart*".

Comment: I would say that dynamic is very rarely considered 'required' and in this case certainly isn't

Comment: @Amit `dynamic` exists for interoping with dynamic languages.  This has nothing to do with that.

Comment: @Servy **if** you have control over *exMethod* that's right. If that's some lame API you have no control of -> `dynamic`.

Comment: @Amit Anonymous classes are internal, so if it's in an API that you don't have access to then `dynamic` *wouldn't work*.  It's *only* an option when you have control over the implementation of the method.