# Anonymous object ~ object does not contain a definition for property

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0

The following code will not compile if I include f1().

However, I see both X & Y in intellisense with their values at the call to calculationXY() in the call from f2().

The f1() compile error is: `object does not contain a definition or x {or for y for that matter` and the .x is red underlined.

```
private object calculateXY(int id) {
    // bla bla bla
    return (new { x = calX, y = calY });
}

/*
f1() {
    var p = calculateXY(10);
    p.x + 1;    
}
*/

f2() {
    var p = calculateXY(10);
    //p.x + 1; 
}
```

Comment: claculateXY returns an `object` .. which has no x or y properties;
you can return a `dynamic` instead, or use reflection to read x and y

Comment: `f2()` won't compile either. It doesn't help that you haven't provided proper  method declarations (and that you're ignoring .NET naming conventions). Please provide a [mcve] and state your problem more clearly... but note that the return type of `calculateXY` is `object`, so that's the compile-time type of `p`.

Comment: @KMoussa how do I fix calculateXY() to return what I expect?  I don't HAVE to formally declare a type do I?

Comment: @Steve try `dynamic` instead of `object`

Comment: @JonSkeet Can you edit the code to show what you want to see? I don't understand what you saying.

Comment: As @KMoussa states, you're returning an `object`. Best bet is to return `dynamic`, but if you're returning an object, you should just return a proper class or struct.

Comment: No, the link I've provided explains what a [mcve] is, and it's not clear why you've got two methods at all, with the same body except for (now) the second line of `f2` being commented out. Fundamentally, the compile-time type of `p` is `object`, and that doesn't contain a member called `x`, so it's not clear why you'd expect it to compile.

Comment: @JonSkeet It's perfectly clear why he'd expect it to compile. He doesn't know C#. Clear as day. He doesn't know the language, he doesn't understand how typing works in the language. He thinks it might be late binding like JavaScript.

Comment: @KMoussa & @TyCobb I guess I'll return a struct.  `dynamic` requires a reference to System.Runtime.CompilerServices.DymanicAttributes which for some reason  this workstation doesn't have (head scratcher).  Thanks.

Comment: Dynamic requires .Net 3.0+

Comment: Dynamic only makes things worse - everything will appear to work fine, until one day, you pass that anonymous object to another assembly, or the runtime changes one of its implementation details, and everything breaks down.

Comment: @Amy: .NET 4.0+, not 3.0.

Comment: I also very much doubt that you really see `x` and `y` in Intellisense within `f2`. You'd see them in the *debugger*, but that's a different matter.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1329672/is-there-a-way-to-return-anonymous-type-from-method and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10073319/returning-anonymous-type-in-c-sharp - this is not possible

Answer (score 2):

I'm added this just to complete the answer.
In the whole solution this class is only instantiated twice. And it is small so I think I'm okay.

```
public class plotPoint {
    public plotPoint (int x, int y){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
    public int x { get; set; }
    public int y { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
private plotPoint calculateXY(int id) { 
    //bla bla bla 
    return (new plotPoint(_pointX, _pointY));
}
```

Although I don't exactly love the name.

I guess I've been doing to much javascript lately.  JS would have a problem with what I was hoping to get away with.  Oh well.

And so we see the death of yet another pointlessly crazy use of a global variable.

Thanks for everyone's input.

Comment: I don't love the name either. I suggested `IntPoint` because there are already at least two `Point` classes in various .NET namespaces, at least one using `float` rather than `int`. Making your `x` and `y` properties rather than fields may not be necessary, depending on what you're doing with it, but it's well within the envelope. And the parametered constructor is a good idea.

Comment: `System.Drawing.Point` is already an integer `Point` class, but that's from Windows Forms, and I don't know if it's appropriate or not for you to use that namespace in the code you're currently working on. If this is winforms UI code, use that. If it's not UI code, ask around if it's considered sensible to use `System.Drawing` stuff in non-UI code. It would bug me a bit but I'd usually be OK with it.

Comment: paramtertized constructor makes for east return in my case `private plotPoint calculateXY(int id)
        {
bla bla bla 
            return (new plotPoint(_pointX, _pointY));
        }`  but that also requires properties doesn't it?

Comment: No, with fields that constructor would look the same.

Comment: Added two more options to my answer. I dislike `Tuple` intensely; the pair of `out` parameters is actually not a bad solution at all, especially for a private helper method.

Comment: started programming in c v3 (think Kernighan & Ritchie).  The 'out' parameter just grates wrong.  To much like VB.. Lol

Comment: Hey, I learned C from K&R1 back in 1995. With an ANSI compiler. Good times! Think of it as `calculate_xy(int n, int * px, int * py)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127200/discussion-between-steve-and-ed-plunkett).

Answer (score 0):

> calculateXY returns an object .. which has no x or y properties; you
>   can return a dynamic instead, or use reflection to read x and y –
>   **KMoussa**

and

> As @KMoussa states, you're returning an object. Best bet is to return
>   dynamic, but if you're returning an object, you should just return a
>   proper class or struct. – **TyCobb**

Thanks guys.

Comment: If you find it uncomfortable making explicit classes for objects, you might want to check out F# - it's a lot more "inferred" than C#, with far less explicit typing. If you want to use C# anyway, best learn how things are done the C# way - anonymous types shouldn't really leave their scope (note how even in LINQ, the anonymous type operations are all in the scope of their containing method - you only ever touch them using anonymous functions defined in the same method).

Comment: btw, you might also want to consider a Tuple<int, int> https://www.dotnetperls.com/tuple

Comment: @KMoussa  interesting :-)  never used that Tuple (outside is SQL) before.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend writing an `IntPoint` class:

```
public class IntPoint { int X; int Y; }
```

And return that. Make sure you declare the method's return type as `IntPoint` as well, so you can easily use the return value without any nonsense:

```
private IntPoint CalculateXY(int id) {
    // bla bla bla
    return new IntPoint { X = calX, Y = calY };
}

...

IntPoint ip = CalculateXY(12);

Console.WriteLine(ip.X);
```

I would not advise using `dynamic` for this. If you do it the way I suggest above, that puts the compiler in your corner, working on your behalf to make sure that any code that calls your method knows what it's getting and uses it properly. `dynamic` is meant for other things, usually fairly exotic things -- I've known about it for years and never yet used it in production code.

Anonymous types, like in your original example, are virtually never returned from methods. That's exotic stuff too, for reasons you discovered already. It's a little more hassle to find a suitable return type sometimes (or write one, as we did above), but it's generally worth the effort.

## UPDATE

Here's another option:

```
private void CalculateXY(int id, out int x, out int y) {
    // bla bla bla
    x = calX;
    y = calY;
}
```

Call like...

```
int x, y;

CalculateXY(32, out int x, out int y);
```

It's not my absolute favorite, but it's an option that's strongly typed, properly named, and doesn't require writing a new class just to hold a return type. I wouldn't mind seeing that in code.

In comments, @KMoussa suggested `Tuple<int,int>` for a return type. That's feasible, and if it's a private helper function it's not the worst thing you can do, but if the code is being maintained the "Item2 *who*?" cost over time will exceed the up-front cost of writing a quickie class. `Tuple` was, IIRC, originally designed to do what anonymous types are now used for.

Comment: I considered going there but didn't really want to create a new class in this code I'm working on for someone else.  I don't understand the entire purpose of this project or these change requests.  Thank you though

Comment: If this is production code, using `dynamic` with an anonymous type for a method return value is malpractice. If a new programmer checked in that code where I work, we'd have a quiet and potentially intense conversation about it in the conference room.

Comment: You know what.  I'f I'm willing to change this that I return an object,  (an object in context is little more than just a pointer isn't it?) then why wouldn't I just make the class.  Not much different is it?

Comment: Not much, no. Very much worth the effort IMHO in maintainability terms. If this is a sizeable code base, I might first look (or ask!) around for an existing class that'll do the job.

Comment: @EdPlunkett I agree in the general case, and I'd say returning `object` isn't much better than `dynamic`; but if the method is a private helper method that's not expected to be used outside that class then it's not as bad .. returning a Tuple might work too

Comment: @KMoussa `Tuple`'s better than object, true. It's a horror instead of an abomination.