# How to return either all properties or a selection of it in C# using LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq, anonymous-types

I have a method that accepts a lambda expression specifying which columns to select from a table `MyTable`.

```
public List<T> GetSelection<T>(string a, Expression<Func<MyTable, T>> columnsToSelect = null)
{
    IQueryable<MyTable> query = _myTableRepository.Where(c => c.Name == a);

    if (columnsToSelect != null)
        return query.Select(columnsToSelect).ToList();

    return query.ToList(); // Intellisense gives an error here, please read on
}
```

As you can see, the `columnsToSelect` has a default value of `null`, allowing me to call this method in any of the following two ways:

```
// passing in a lambda expression to select the columns I want
var result = GetSelection("AValue", t => new { t.Prop1, t.Prop2 }); 

// or like this, in which case I want all the columns
var result = GetSelection("AValue");
```

The error I get from intellisense is this:

> Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List' to
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List'

Firstly, I don't understand this confusing error message, but I am not much bothered about it. That said, what I think I need is a way to convert the whole object of `MyTable` into an anonymous type and then return the list of it, and by *whole object* I mean the anonymous type object will contain all the properties of `MyTable`. How can I achieve that?

OR, if there is any other better way to accomplish what I want, please suggest that.

Comment: I think the only way to make this KIND OF work, would be to return `object`. Or `dynamic`. Lookie here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10073319/returning-anonymous-type-in-c-sharp

Comment: @HristoYankov Thanks, but I am very much against using dynamic, unless I really really have to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> allowing me to call this method in any of the following two ways:
>
> ...
>
> ```
> var result = GetSelection("AValue");
> ```

No, that wouldn't be allowed. There's no way the compiler can infer a type for `T` here. The only way around that is by creating overloads instead of using default values. At which point the problem becomes trivial to solve:

```
public List<T> GetSelection<T>(
    string a, Expression<Func<MyTable, T>> columnsToSelect)
{
    return _myTableRepository.Where(c => c.Name == a).Select(columnsToSelect)
        .ToList();
}

public List<MyTable> GetSelection<MyTable>(string a)
{
    return GetSelection(a, t => t);
}
```

Comment: I didn't see that I couldn't call it that way. Sorry for that. So in that case, as you have already said, the problem becomes trivial. I will stick with an overloaded version methinks. Or just call it the way you've done in the expression less overload you've shown.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do this:

```
if (columnsToSelect != null)
{
    var result = query.Select(s => s.GetType().GetProperty("columnName").GetValue(s, null).ToString())
                      .Select(s => new MyTable()
                      {
                          YourProperty = s.ToString()
                      }).ToList();
}
```

Comment: But I am not into using reflection and all that when I can use simpler approach, like what [hvd](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42605942/3375713) has shown. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Plus it can't be used in LINQ to SQL (haven't tried it out though, but I'm quite certain of that).

Answer (score 1):

If you could define an interface for your table

```
public interface IMyTable<T>
{
    string Name { get; set; }
    T GetAll();
}
```

then this would compile

```
public List<T> GetSelection<T>(string a, Expression<Func<IMyTable<T>, T>> columnsToSelect = null)
{
    IQueryable<IMyTable<T>> query  = (IQueryable<IMyTable<T>>) _myTableRepository.Where(c => c.Name == a);

    if (columnsToSelect == null)
        columnsToSelect = (Expression<Func<IMyTable<T>, T>>)(table => (table.GetAll()));

    return query.Select(columnsToSelect).ToList();

}
```

A demo for the usage

```
IMyTable<List<object>> xxx = new MyTable() { Surname = "b", Addresss = 1 };
xxx.Name = "a";
IMyTable<List<object>> yyy = new MyTable() { Surname = "d", Addresss = 2 };
yyy.Name = "c";
var repo = new List<IMyTable<List<object>>>() { xxx, yyy }.AsQueryable();
var Test = new Test<List<object>>(repo);
var generic = Test.GetSelection<List<object>>("c");
var specific = Test.GetSelection<List<object>>("c",
                (Expression<Func<IMyTable<List<object>>, List<object>>>) 
                    (x => new List<object>() { x.Name, ((MyTable)x).Addresss }));
var specifc2Columns = specific
    .Select(rows => new { Name = rows[0], Address = rows[1] });
```

where the demo table is

```
 internal class MyTable : IMyTable<List<object>>
 {
     public string Surname { get; set; }
     public int Addresss { get; set; }
     string IMyTable<List<object>>.Name{ get; set; }
     List<object> IMyTable<List<object>>.GetAll()
     {
         return new List<object>() { ((IMyTable<List<object>>)this).Name, Surname, Addresss };
     }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for all that you've shown. But I think you will agree too that what [hvd](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42605942/3375713) has shown is a simpler approach.

Comment: I don't think this would even work. The use of `Expression<...>` suggests that a query provider is being used other than `EnumerableQuery` is being used (otherwise, a simple `Func<...>` would be better). And query providers don't generally like calls to custom methods. Aside from that, it would surprise me if returning the property values for each `MyTable` instance in rows rather than columns is what's intended, and it's very fragile in that `(Expression<Func<IMyTable<T>, T>>)` will fail at run-time unless `T` is exactly `List<string>`, which is not clear to callers.

Comment: @hvd do you want me to show a working example? Let me update the answer in a minute

Comment: @hvd look at `var specific = `

Comment: @user1892538 You're using `EnumerableQuery` though (by calling `AsQueryable()` on something that isn't already an `IQueryable`), which is more tolerant than other providers.

Comment: @hvd about your last point, really I did it just to build a quick demo...

Comment: @hvd "*Aside from that, it would surprise me if returning the property values for each `MyTable` instance in rows rather than columns is what's intended*" => then I've add a `var specifc2Columns =` ...