# Method that returns anonymous type C#

Tags: c#

I have this type of variable :

[image]

What kind of return type should I write for my method? I wrote `object` but it didn't work out. Thanks.

EDIT :

I made such classes :

```
public class IlIlceTarife
{
    public string Il { get; set; }
    public string Ilce { get; set; }
    public string Tarife { get; set; }
}

public class a
{
   public IlIlceTarife Name { get; set; }
    public int Sayi { get; set; }
}
```

And I made return type as this :

```
public List<IEnumerable<a>> TarifeGiver1(string il, string ilce)
```

And VS gave this error :

```
> Cannot implicitly convert type
> 'System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<<anonymous
> type: <anonymous type: string Il, string Ilce, string Tarife> Name,
> int Sayi>>>' to
> 'System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<WebApplication2.Controllers.a>>'
```

Comment: Write a class instead.

Comment: Why you give a class a name `a`? That's the most inapprorpiate name i can imagine

Comment: @TimSchmelter I was going to change it later. Just wrote it quickly.

Comment: What is the body of the TaifeGiver1 function?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Returning anonymous type in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10073319/returning-anonymous-type-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't return an anonymous type. Instead you should create a regular named class and use that as return type.

Anonymous types are good when their scope is just inside the method itself. They have no use outside the method. How would you for example know the property names if their definition is not public? The only solution is to create a class.

If you still want to return an anonymous type, you should return `object` or `dynamic`, both I am not really happy about when using that as return type.

---

Regarding your update: you have to use the named types in the code initializing the instances too (probably LINQ). C# doesn't automatically convert anonymous types to named types.

Comment: Please see my edit. I have done what you said but it gave error.

Comment: And as Tim says: give the class a real name.

Comment: You have `new {` somewhere, replace that by `new SomeType {`.

Comment: No, it's giving two errors: 1.Invalid initializer member declarator 2. Cannot initialize type 'IlIlceTarife' with a collection initializer because it does not implement 'System.Collections.IEnumerable'

Comment: Maybe it is better to ask a new question with the current code you have.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43605936/how-to-use-objects-instead-of-anonymous-types Here is my new question.

Comment: Thanks for accepting my other answer. Can we close this one too? @jason

Comment: Now as of C# 7 you also have the option of `ValueTuple` instead of just `object` or `dynamic` for "declarationless" return types.