# Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<<anonymous type: string BaseTypeTitle, string BaseTypeCode to 'System.Collections.Generi

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, linq, lambda

I want to join 3 tables form their contexts with linq or lambda but I get an error.

This is my linq

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OENlv.png)

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<TblCharityAccount>> GetAccountasync()
{
    BaseData_Contexts db1 = new BaseData_Contexts();
    BaseType_Context db2 = new BaseType_Context();

    var joined = (from ep in _db.TblCharityAccounts
                  join e in db1.TblCommonBaseData on ep.BankId equals e.CommonBaseDataId
                  join c in db2.TblCommonBaseTypes on e.CommonBaseTypeId equals c.CommonBaseTypeId
                  select new 
                         {
                             c.BaseTypeTitle,
                             c.BaseTypeCode,
                             c.CommonBaseTypeId,
                             e.BaseCode,
                             e.BaseValue,
                             e.CommonBaseDataId
                         });

    return joined;
}
```

Error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<<anonymous type: string BaseTypeTitle, string BaseTypeCode, int CommonBaseTypeId, string BaseCode, string BaseValue, int CommonBaseDataId>>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<CharityAccounts.Model.TblCharityAccount>'.

Comment: Select instances of `TblCharityAccount` instead of creating anonymous types

Comment: can u tell me how?

Comment: can u whirte this lambda or linq for me

Comment: Use `new TblCharityAccount { ... }` instead of `new { ... }` or maybe you can simply use `select ep`

Answer (score 0):

You are returning `Task<IEnumerable<TblCharityAccount>>` however ***joined*** consists of a list of anonymous types. I added a ToList() not sure exactly if this is what you wanted but i'm assuming this is entity framework and entity framework is deferred execution. Also you have not provided if TblCharityAccount fits the same bill as your anonymous type so you may need to create a new type for this.

```
public class JoinTableResult
{
    public string BaseTypeTitle { get ; set; }
    public string BaseTypeCode { get ; set; }
    public string CommonBaseTypeId { get ; set; }
    public string BaseCode { get ; set; }
    public string BaseValue { get ; set; }
    public string CommonBaseDataId { get ; set; }
}

public async Task<IEnumerable<JoinTableResult>> GetAccountasync()
{
    BaseData_Contexts db1 = new BaseData_Contexts();
    BaseType_Context db2 = new BaseType_Context();

    var joined = (from ep in _db.TblCharityAccounts
                        join e in db1.TblCommonBaseData on ep.BankId equals e.CommonBaseDataId
                        join c in db2.TblCommonBaseTypes on e.CommonBaseTypeId equals c.CommonBaseTypeId
                        select new 
                        {
                            c.BaseTypeTitle,
                            c.BaseTypeCode,
                            c.CommonBaseTypeId,
                            e.BaseCode,
                            e.BaseValue,
                            e.CommonBaseDataId
                        }).ToList();
    return joined;
}
```

Comment: how i can use this code instead <tblcharityaccount> wht can i send return

Comment: You need to define a type you can't return an anonymous type which is what you have, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/10073345/5963888,

If you don't want to use <tblecharityaccount> you will have to create another type to select to.

Comment: I edited my answer to show you how to get this to work over your anonymous test.. I don't know your types so i just used string for all of them in the JoinedTableResult  class