# How I can pass the LINQ result anonymous type to another method?

Tags: c#, linq

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I pass an anonymous type to a method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55101/how-can-i-pass-an-anonymous-type-to-a-method)

I want to pass the collection of LINQ result to another method

This is the LinQ code

```
var sets =
        from a in patient
        from b in patient
        from c in patient
        from d in patient
        from l in patient
        where a.VisitNum < b.VisitNum && b.VisitNum < c.VisitNum && c.VisitNum < d.VisitNum && d.VisitNum < l.VisitNum
        select new { a, b, c, d, l };
```

The query present the result like this "combinations"

```
   ID    Visit DAte       Visit number    Rational 
    -------------------------------------------------
   a- 1     14/05/2011           1           new
   b- 1     15/06/2012           2           Emergency 
   c- 1     17/07/2012           3           Check-Up

   a- 1     14/05/2011           1           new
   b- 1     15/06/2012           2           Emergency 
   c- 1     18/12/2012           5           Check-Up
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`new { a, b, c, d, l }` creates an item of [anonymous type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx) so return value of entire LINQ query results in an anonymous type as well. To pass such value in a method I would suggest converting it to a known type. Just introduce a new class and an interface if you would like abstract a method from a concrete implementation:

It is not clear what query does and which item types are so update class and type names accordingly:

```
interface IResultSet
{
   TypeA A { get; }
   TypeB B { get; }
   TypeC C { get; }
   TypeD D { get; }
   TypeL L { get; }
}

class ResultSet : IResultSet
{
   public ResultSet(inject all property values here) {}

   public TypeA A { get; private set; }
   public TypeB B { get; private set; }
   public TypeC C { get; private set; }
   public TypeD D { get; private set; }
   public TypeL L { get; private set; }
}

IEnumerable<IResultSet> sets =
    from a in patient
    from b in patient
    from c in patient
    from d in patient
    from l in patient
    where a.VisitNum < b.VisitNum 
          && b.VisitNum < c.VisitNum 
          && c.VisitNum < d.VisitNum 
          && d.VisitNum < l.VisitNum
    select new ResultSet(a, b, c, d, l);
```

And keep in mind that LINQ `Select()` has deffered execution so query itself will not be executed until you access result set enumeration, so if you need to execute it immediately just add `.ToList()` call at the query end:

Deffered:

```
ProcessData(sets);
```

Immediate execution:

```
ProcessData(sets.ToList());

// Now you can pass results in a method like this
public void ProcessData(IEnumerable<IResultSet> items)
```

And finally I would suggest NOT using `dynamic` type to abstract such anonymous types, you can use it but in some special cases so it would be adequate decision. In your case it will  makes code less readable and broke type safety, `dynamic` perfectly fits for [DSL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-specific_language) engines and things to handle dynamic structure data but not to be a silver bullet for those who badly know OOP basics.

Comment: This is the only right answer. Using reflection or `dynamic` tricks is a recipe for confusion and performance problems.

Comment: How i can get this class IResultSet ?

Comment: `IResultSet` is interface not a class. Added definition, see updated answer

Comment: I got error on new Resultset the error message is Error  'Iteration2.ResultSet' does not contain a constructor that takes 0 argument

Comment: and this error too Error 8 Cannot initialize type 'Iteration2.ResultSet' with a collection initializer because it does not implement 'System.Collections.IEnumerable

Comment: I suppose you did following: `var resultSet = new ResultSet();` - will complain about default ctor with 0 parameters. And `new ResultSet { sets }` - will complain about latter error you've mentioned. Just use code snipped I've provided

Comment: considering you've marked answer as accepted does this mean everything is clear for you? You are welcome in case of any question, please do not hesitate

Answer (score 1):

You can't pass anonymous type directly to another method, by there is few workaround:

First of all you can pass it via `dynamic` parameter:

```
var at = new { a = 1, b = 2, c = 3, d = 4, l = 5 };
ProcessAnonymousType(at);

void ProcessAnonymousType(dynamic at)
{
  Console.WriteLine("Anonymous type data: {0}, {1}, {2}", at.a, at.b, at.c);
}
```

You can pass anonymous type instance via object and use reflection to access to the properties (actually this is pretty similar to previous one, but with more efforts from your side):

```
void ProcessAnonymousType(object at)
{
    // Use reflection to access a, b, c properties
}
```

And, as always you can use named type instead.

Comment: @downvoter: I'm not stated that this is **good** way to do. But only few workarounds. If you'll take a look at my answer the first statement is: "You can't pass anonymous type directly to another method". I know all pros and cons for my advice.

Comment: I tried your solution but i got an error message there is no diffinition for a in "at"

Comment: I did not get any type of the list but i get int a ,b,c,d,l are list item in patient list

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the typed parameter (as well as anonymous typed) like this:

```
void Method<T>(T obj)
{
}
```

And then use the reflection to extract all the public properties stored inside.
Any anon-typed variable **could** be passed as a parameter like so:

```
var item = new { Foo = 1, Bar = "2" };
Method(item);
```

And there will be no exceptions.
As for the reflection, this code

```
object[] values = typeof(T)
    .GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public)
    .Select(W => W.GetValue(obj, null)).ToArray();
```

Will produce an array of the public properties of your item inside the `Method` method. [`Result image`](http://pasteboard.co/1faJ1zRr.png).

Comment: I got it  it works fine now Can I use it as values.a ?

Comment: I did not have an access to the type because a, b, , c ,d,l are list has different elements

Comment: @Wimaxmax you do have the access to the type, because your type is defined inside `GetProperties` result. The result is `PropertyInfo[]` (an array) and is contains values, types, access modifiers and other useful stuff.

Comment: Downvoted because while this is a solution, it's not the right solution. Anonymous types plus reflection is an expensive hack when simply creating a named type will suffice and be far easier to understand and maintain and it will perform better.

Comment: @siride it depends on author's needs.

Comment: @AgentFire: I can't fathom a single situation in which this solution is the best one.

Comment: @siride like MVC uses the same approach.

Comment: @AgentFire: that doesn't mean it's a good approach. The general .NET framework has many misdesigns.