# Select By Key Values from a LINQ Query in a view

Tags: vb.net, asp.net-mvc-3, linq, entity-framework, razor

I am trying to grab each key value from a LINQ Query and pull them into my view. The LINQ query looks like this:

```
Public Property ByVDN As IEnumerable
    Get
        Dim valQ = (From scr In Var.db.CareSideA.ScriptCrossReferences
                   Join s In Var.db.CareSideA.Scripts On s.ScriptID Equals scr.ScriptID
                   Join ms In Var.db.CareSideA.MasterScripts On s.MasterScriptID Equals ms.MasterScriptID
                   Join svce In Var.db.CareSideA.Services On svce.SkillTargetID Equals scr.ForeignKey
                   Join p In Var.db.CareSideA.Peripherals On svce.PeripheralID Equals p.PeripheralID
                   Join sm In Var.db.CareSideA.ServiceMembers On svce.SkillTargetID Equals sm.ServiceSkillTargetID
                   Join sg In Var.db.CareSideA.SkillGroups On sm.SkillGroupSkillTargetID Equals sg.SkillTargetID
                   Where s.Version = ms.CurrentVersion And scr.TargetType = 1 And svce.PeripheralNumber = Value
                   Select New With {Key .Service = svce.PeripheralNumber,
                                    Key .ScriptName = ms.EnterpriseName,
                                    Key .Peripheral = p.EnterpriseName,
                                    Key .SkillMapping = sg.PeripheralNumber,
                                    Key .LatestVersion = s.Version,
                                    Key .Created = s.DateTime,
                                    Key .Author = s.Author}).ToList
        Return valQ
    End Get
    Set(value As IEnumerable)
    End Set
End Property
```

Now this does return results but they look like this: [image: Screen Shot]

Ideally I'd like to be able to do this:

```
<table>
For Each Item In Model.ByVDN
  Dim i = Item
    <tr>
      <td>@Html.DisplayFor(Function(m) i.Service)</td>
      <td>@Html.DisplayFor(Function(m) i.ScriptName)</td>
      <td>@Html.DisplayFor(Function(m) i.Peripheral)</td>
   Next
```

etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't pass about anonymous objects. [Well, you can, but it is not strongly typed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6624811/how-to-pass-anonymous-types-as-parameters). You'll have to define a class with these properties, create IEnumerable of instances of that class and pass that Enumerable to the view. There is no other way.

UPD: see similar question: [passing linq select query to the method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16823658/passing-linq-select-query-to-the-method?lq=1)

Comment: Over last 2 years of working with MVC I've came to conclusion that it is worth the effort to create a view model per view. Especially if the application does something non-basic and you plan to develop it further.

Comment: I couldn't agree more. That's exactly what I would be doing, however we're on a code freeze until Feb. And I can't push the new view to our SQL servers until then "/

Comment: How C# classes for view models are connected to your SQL Server views?  What is your workflow?

Comment: unfortunately I'm having to follow a database first approach.  My company had a .NET developer who learned how to develop asp.net forms while he worked here, did a crap job, demanded a $10000 raise and left when he didn't get his way.  I was hired to clean up the mess.  Also everything has to be written in vb.net not c# unfortunately.

Comment: For EF Code First you don't need to create a SQL view to have a view model, either in C# or VB

Comment: can you hit me with a link or some keywords to search on for how to do what your saying?

Comment: I think you need this article http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2009/06/30/how-we-do-mvc-view-models/  - there will be plenty of info and keywords for further research. Jimmy Bogard has a good blog about MVC - worth reading every single post.

Comment: hm... also this one (probably I'd start with this one, then the one above): http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2012/04/10/asp-net-web-api-mvc-viewmodels-and-formatters/